# Can we make the title rules more consistent when creating and editing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-question, asking-questions, title

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55282719/revisions) question was created with the following title:

> OneToMany relation working on Prisma Database, but not on server!

I noticed the emoji and went to remove it (not noticing the `!`) and it gave me the following error:

> These words are not allowed in titles: '!'.. See [Writing Good Titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648).

Fair enough, I removed the `!` too but I was wondering why, if the `!` is not allowed to be used when editing the title is it allowed to be used when on creation. Ideally, it should be prevented in both places or allowed in both places.

Can we make this more consistent?

Comment: @yivi that's a good point, let me try and test it here. **Edit:** It seems that meta doesn't like `?!`, it seems to cut off the `!` in `?!`?

Comment: Maybe an additional feature request. Disallow emojis in titles?

Comment: I agree on @Lino: Some Emoji can be very aggressive, or any how innapropriate. Crying face [https://emojipedia.org/crying-face/] is ok, but a Emoji filter will be too complicated, I guess.

Comment: @Lino  I suggested that on Meta here before a year or more back and was downvoted to hell, apparently people like their emojis ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @opa can you please link it here, I'd love to give it an up-vote.

Comment: @Chris_Rands That would be another topic. I'm just talking about making the existing rule consistent (whichever way that would be).

Comment: @Lino https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381660/can-we-stop-emojis-being-a-part-of-question-titles

Comment: Independent of exclamation marks at the end, I quite often try to edit a question and get told that the title, which I haven't yet changed, is not acceptable.  Or I edit a typo in the title and am told that the title isn't acceptable for reasons apparently unrelated to the typo I fixed.  It is extremely irksome when that happens.

Comment: I just got an example: there was a question with the title 'Error on my semicolon seems unfixable' which isn't OK, but I haven't tried to edit the damn title and to burninate the semicolon tag I've now got to work out how the f*****g title can be fixed, which is unnecessarily painful (hence the masked expletive!).  — The title is now 'How to fix this error from a semicolon which seems to be unfixable?' but I still object to the system making me modify the title rather than subjecting the OP to the indignity of making a title fit for SO!

Comment: This title should be more consistent. I thought the question is about titles that do not match the actual topic

Comment: @Adelin I believe you misunderstood the purpose of this question. I'm not trying to solve misinterpretations of question titles and no doubt, misinterpretations are inevitable with the vast number of different users throughout the website.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As yivi noted, the prohibition on ending a title with ! is by design. However, we could've been a bit more clear about that, so... Now you'll see a message like this:

[image: "Title cannot end in an exclamation point!"]

More specificity as to *where* the exclamation point is prohibited will hopefully reduce confusion in situations like the one you encountered.

Answer (score 36):

This does not look like a bug, but actually [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

What's blocking you is leaving the question ending on "!". Which admittedly, is not great. Titles as exclamations are very close to shouting.

Exclamation marks on the middle of a title are fine and can go through, which makes sense, because **the exclamation mark can have a lot of perfectly acceptable meanings in a valid programming related title**:

> [image: exclamation mark middle of sentence]

But not at the end, which also makes sense. We do not want shouty titles. We hate fun and users shouting.

> [image: this looks like an actual exclamation!!!1!one]

The emoji at the end of that title was confusing the regex into thinking that title was **not** an exclamation, when it actually was.

The appropriate edit for that title would have been to remove **both** the emoji character and the exclamation mark.

*If* there is a bug here is allowing emojis on the first place, but I'm not sure if those are trivially blocked, nor if there is anything to gain by blocking them.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, I'm going to hold off accepting the answer for little bit to see if we can get an "official" response, if not, I'll go ahead and accept this.

Comment: one reason for letting it remain in the middle of a title is because of its prolific use in logic syntax, i.e. 'a != b'; and in mathematic operations questions like 'why is 3! equal to 6'

Comment: Still, the  error message is not exactly correct: ":" is not a word, and it doesn't mention about being at the end of the title.

Comment: Related: [Stop rewriting trailing exclamation marks as question marks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115352): "*We're forbidding **trailing** `!`s in question titles on the trilogy*" (emphasis mine)

Comment: So asking 'why is 3! equal to 6' is fine, but if you ask 'why is 6 equal to 3!' then, well, SO does not approve that.

Comment: Emojis are (more or less) trivially blocked: [they are a specific set of Unicode characters](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).