#  Can we stop emojis being a part of question titles? 

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions, title

They add very little (no?) value to the actual question title and it should be classed as "noise".

I do believe that it falls within the same category as including the programming language in your question title.

<sup>This request was inspired by [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381652/can-we-make-the-title-rules-more-consistent-when-creating-and-editing?noredirect=1#comment680483_381652) comment made by [@Lino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5515060/lino).</sup>

Comment: What if I have a question about a specific emoji? 

Comment: @Floern you can resolve the name of the emoji via: https://getemoji.com which for your case would lead to [thinking-face](https://emojipedia.org/thinking-face). So maybe add that to the title?

Comment: @Floern not sure if that is sarcasm / joke, but, IMO, you could include the emoji in your body and formulate your title without it. Would that not work?

Comment: @Floern eg : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618487/why-are-emoji-characters-like-treated-so-strangely-in-swift-strings

Comment: @SurajRao kudos for finding that and I guess it may have real world uses after all but what do you think about my above suggestion to @Floern?

Comment: This is abused so rarely it would be a waste of time to implement .

Comment: @Turnip I envisage the usage to increase a lot more (I've personally seen more questions than before with emojis) but I see what you mean.

Comment: @Script47 sure, it's easy to work around if I have a legit question. But on the other hand it's not that much of a problem to invest the time to implement that filter.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342024

Comment: There's no "we", it is Shog9 that has to type in the regex rule.  I'll stick up my hand to say I hope he won't.  Beyond it possibly being useful in a title, these regex rules go wrong too often.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I’m gonna do this from now on.

Comment: Thinking retrospectively, you should have used  [Question Title] ... so that when it appeared in **Hot Meta Posts** it was accurate!

Comment: I flagged as a dupe of [     ?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342024) because the same principles apply. Just because emojis are tackier it does not warrant their banishment as discussed in that post.

Comment: What if I have a question about [emojicode](https://www.emojicode.org/) here? Those are bound to have emoji's in the title.

Comment: These are great, can we start using them now?  = burnination request,  = homework request and so on.

Comment: These emojis only render on my work machine.  At home I just get boxes.  I'd fix it but I really don't wanna look at these emojis...

Comment: @Turnip:  Now that this is a Hot Meta Question, expect to see more in the near future.  Maybe doubling the number of questions with emojis in from one to two, a 100% increase.

Comment: This is the crappiest  idea I've ever heard of.

Comment: Valid use-case: [How can a tag badge for  be tracked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382516/4642212).

Comment: @Lundin if that's workable then make it a feature-request! it'd be helpful to see flames on the deprecated tags when they due to start disappearing

Answer (score 143, accepted):

This is the first time I've ever seen an emoji in a question title.

The second time is when I followed your link to the cited SO question.

Therefore I do not believe that they are in any way a problem. Certainly they have nothing to do with adding the programming language in your question title (which is a duplication of tags).

Whether a particular character in a title is "noise" should be taken on a case-by-case basis (just edit it out if you don't like it!), not by summarily banning entire swathes of the character set. That's what Cersei Lannister would have done!

**tl;dr: Adding yet more "things you can't do" is not called for here.**

Comment: Fair enough, thought it'd be worth a shot and see how the community would react (by looking at the +1 rate of your answer, I have my answer, it just flew from 0-9 within seconds).

Comment: Fresh off the meta hotlist! (This is honestly a good example of why people may want to use emojis in the first place - this title evidently draws everyone to it.)

Comment: Obviously it was my intention to make you look so good. (In all seriousness I'm fascinated at the rate of the incline ***cough*** inside job... voter fraud ***cough***).

Comment: @Script47 Cheque's in the post

Comment: @MaxLanghof I'd think that the question would have a lot more negative press on the main site.

Comment: @Script47 Yes, I didn't mean to imply that it was a _good_ or _valid_ reason for using them, but that your original concern was correct. You couldn't have given better proof of the problem than what is happening here, even though your suggestion isn't necessary for "fixing" it.

Comment: I guess we are100 people that first saw an emoji in the title of that very question :)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNuH5.png

Comment: For the record, in 2018, I run a query and edited **many** superfluous emojis from titles: this may explain why there are so few left.

Comment: A lot of spam questions use emoji in the title (especially over the last week), but it seems like they get deleted quickly due to Charcoal/Smoke Detector. The posts certainly do exist, though.