# How can a tag badge for  be tracked?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-badges

While viewing [a user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy?tab=topactivity), I found that the next tag badge being tracked is the bronze  badge. [There is not even a  badge](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%F0%9F%91%BE%5D), and I don't understand how or why this is possible.

[image]

So, uhh, what's the deal with this? Is it intentional behavior?

Comment: Perhaps they created the tag briefly, choose it as the next tag, then removed the tag? Probably unrelated, but that user was [once a diamond moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6).

Comment: @WaiHaLee tags need to be used by 100+ questions to be elibible for tag badges ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for#68395)). I doubt he'd use a tag on 100 questions just to be able to track the badge.

Comment: Ah, I see. That saves me from making the ☃️ tag to add to your question to experiment. BTW this happened when they weren't a mod - it was after [November 2018](http://web.archive.org/web/20181107173436/https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy?tab=topactivity).

Comment: Also, this is a perfect example for why [emojis shouldn’t be banned from titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381660/4642212).

Comment: Or, a perfect example of why emojis should be banned ***everywhere***, @Xufox.

Comment: I gave up on the ` Python` badge.

Comment: It's probably only a matter of time now before people start abusing this to say naughty stuff. (Am I pessimist or realist? You decide.)

Comment: Not a huge deal, @Andrew. You can already put naughty stuff in your profile's "about me" section.

Comment: @Jeremy I was told recently that I am like you. How do you like them apples? :)

Comment: The squid renders differently on every device I have...

Comment: @Jeremy don't worry, you were *undoubtedly* a much better moderator than I ever have been.

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard you have been a mod?

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard no, I haven't. Which means Jeremy (who was a mod) automatically did better at being a moderator than me.

Comment: Back in 2012 I got into dev and retagged 50 posts to `hacker` so the system would create and award me with [the Hacker (tag) Badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122625/implement-the-hacker-badge). Unfortunately, it didn't work: the scheduled task creating/awarding tag badges wasn't running on dev. 

Comment: @TheWanderer It's actually called the [Alien Monster](https://emojipedia.org/alien-monster/) (aka. space invader)

Comment: Wow so you mean anyone can see the actual badges I have set as the next one being tracked? Not being actively tracking any puts me in an uncomfortable situation... What is the message I am sending? Can other people notice it is the one set by the system?

Comment: Your profile name is so cute (your profile pic also) so StackOverflow gave you special emoji that represents your character

Comment: Custom tag badges _and more_ should return on April 1st, 2020.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[Sebastian Simon’s answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382517/1114) describes how I was doing this. Tragically, the attention this has drawn to the bug has caused it to be fixed: trying to set a nonexistent tag now results in an error.

[image: An error pop-up reading "The requested tag does not exist."]

Non-existent tag names that were previously set have been left unmodified (for now). The system still allows you to track a tag that has not reached [the 100-question threshold to have a real tag badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags).

> There was no XSS or SQLi risk here. It was just ... let's go with "unwanted". I haven't sought an official policy decision on the pre-existing data, and it doesn't seem to present any immediate concerns, so for now I've just left them as-is. I don't guarantee that they won't be removed in the future. – [Marc Gravell♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) [6 hours ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382516/how-can-a-tag-badge-for-be-tracked/382610#comment686248_382610)

Comment: Unfortunately they really did fix this bug and I have to accept your answer... But at least it doesn't stop me from tracking the badge I've already started tracking. I can still track [] :)

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard, it looks like they reverted the tags I'd set on other sites but kept the fun ones on SO and MSO (so far).

Comment: So theoretically it could have been used in a XSS attack

Comment: @lalo Naw, I tried that a while ago. The output is encoded correctly, even if it contained unexpected characters.

Comment: Oh nooo! Well… I’m going to keep my fox emoji tag badge tracked… It will also never change the fact that this Q/A post earned me six different badges.

Comment: @lalo no, there was no XSS or SQLi risk here. It was just ... let's go with "unwanted". I haven't sought an official policy decision on the pre-existing data, and it doesn't seem to present any immediate concerns, so for now I've just left them as-is. I don't guarantee that they won't be removed in the future.

Comment: @Xufox Thanx to your amazing discovery I'll keep tracking that unicorn  though I might never catch it ..wait - my coworker just told me that unicorns aren't real - now I should have tracked pandas instead ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix let's start an Unicorn Tracking Club !

Comment: @QuentinHayot Or a unicorn racing club with leprechaun as jockeys and, just in case - the according betting-platform _uni-bet.corn_ ;)

Comment: Earning a tag badge reset the "next tag badge" tracker to a random other badge (not the one I'm most likely to get next). I was tracking [:beer:], I earned the bronze [fft] tag, then all of a sudden found myself tracking [matlab-figure].

Comment: Now, earning the [tag:jquery] bronze badge, I lost my  bronze badge in the tracker… RIP.

Comment: @SebastianSimon A comment on MSE suggests the company reset all of our unusual tags. Mine are gone too.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, Thank this guy for [ruining our fun](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331305/user-is-tracking-tag-badge-for-non-existing-tag-with-emoji).

Answer (score 242):

This answer provides the method of how this used to be achieved and how it used to work. Sadly, this has been fixed now. See [Jeremy’s answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382610/4642212).

---

1. Click on the tag tracker:

   > [image]
2. Open the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit <kbd>F12</kbd>), and inspect one of the options:

   > [image]
3. Look for the `<div>` that has a `data-badge-database-name` attribute, then double-click to edit its value:

   > [image]
4. Change it to , or whatever you like, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the value:

   > [image]
5. Then simply click on the option you’ve manipulated:

   > [image]
6. You’re now tracking a non-existent tag badge:

   > [image]

---

Under the hood, a POST request is sent to the server at step 5. The POST request takes the value from the `data-badge-database-name` attribute verbatim. The request is `POST https://stackoverflow.com/users/activity/next-badge-popup/save` with this body:

```
fkey=(long hex code)
badgeDatabaseName=
isTagBadge=true
```

I’ve also tried to manipulate the POST request directly but had no success in changing the tracked badge.

Comment: Obligatory comment about input validation.

Comment: ☝️ ☝️ ☝️ ☝️ ☝️ ☝️

Comment: Unless there's high potential for harm here, I kind of think this would be a fun Easter egg to leave in.

Comment: @TheWanderer Anyone wants to try a [Bobby Tables tag badge](https://xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: It’s also weird that the length of the tag name is actually validated.

Comment: Thanks, Xufox. Here's [my implementation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/56016/brandon-j?tab=activity). :) This is fun.

Comment: @Xufox I tried to self XSS myself, but it didn't work using multiple techniques I tried

Comment: The question is: can you actually earn this badge?

Comment: @AstroRP If it is created, maybe. Through hacking? Hopefully not…

Comment: @AstroRP Yes. It's called mod abuse and it's a lot of fun! (Wait. Why has my reputation gone down to 1 all of a sud—

Comment: I shouldn't have *this* much fun with this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question of how OP is seeing it on someone else's profile without having made the change themselves. This doesn't persist when you refresh.

Comment: @TylerH But it _does_ persist. See [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/xufox?tab=topactivity) where I’m still tracking the  bronze badge.

Comment: @Xufox When I F5'd after doing this myself, it reverted. But I did it from the current view rather than changing the `data-badge-database-name` attribute, which is apparently (and disturbingly) passed to the SO database.

Comment: @TylerH What is “the current view”? It sounds like you’re just locally editing the DOM.

Comment: @Xufox Yes, that's what I was referring to; I opened up F12 and edited the DOM value of "currently tracked" tag instead of the data attribute of the tag picker.

Comment: This is very cool :D I first thought it might work with the badges as well but it doesn't.

Comment: Tried this and the response said that the King-Penguin----- badge does not exist :(

Comment: It looks like it has been fixed. I still have a tag but I can't change it anymore.

Comment: Lets hope they let the people that used this keep their tags. also, I hope no attacked them

Comment: Y'all ruined my fun! :P

Comment: aww, it seems i'm too late

Comment: RIP custom tag badges, 4/6/19 - 4/8/19

Comment: @QuentinHayot You can still switch _away_ from a non-existent tag, but you can no longer switch _to_ a non-existent tag. So either stick with your current one, or it will be **gone forever**. I had to learn it the hard way :-/

Comment: @SørenD.Ptæus Yup. I'll keep my unicorn.