# For a more considered use of emojis

Tags: discussion, etiquette

This isn't an extensive issue, but the most recent [Data Science Time!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386178/data-science-time-june-2019-and-the-tumbleweed-badge) got me going, as the kids say.

I can appreciate the use of emojis in condensed communication forms like tweets and text messages, where they can convey a lot of information in little space, but in longer form texts, like a blog, or a Stack Overflow meta Q&A I fail to see their merit.

Barring cases where emojis are the actual subject of the text, I see their use as at best a gimmicky flourish, but frequently I find them to detract from the text in one or more ways.

- They're ambiguous, both because they can have jargonistic primary or secondary meanings, and because they render differently depending on character set, assuming they even render at all.
- They add visual clutter and distracts the eye when reading, being often quite large and colorful and placed within the text body.
- They can be interpreted as condescending, informal, or jokey, depending on context and the reader, more so than the authors intent.

Gimmicky flourishes, while groan-inducing for some, can be a matter of personal style for others, so I don't want to discourage the use of emojis outright, but rather encourage a carefully considered use.

Comment: There is also this (MSE): [Do we have a policy on smileys? :)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172143/do-we-have-a-policy-on-smileys)

Comment: I can understand this being posted about _regular_ posts. And emojis are very often removed from posts without any further thought. But the "Data Science Time" are company announcements, more akin to blog posts than regular questions. They are only published here to engage with the meta crowd, as appreciative as it is, and to be able to use the answer/comment facilities for further feedback. I think that applying regular rules to these posts does not help anyone.

Comment: Does it need to be there? If no, remove/don't include it. If yes, include it. This falls into the category of "noise" and we remove "noise".

Comment: Hello  and welcome  to Stack Overflow!  Please remember  to reward  the hard work  of our community ‍‍‍  and upvote  helpful answers. Thank you 

Comment: @franiis: Related, but personally I'm much more OK with simple smileys. As they're made up of more or less regular characters they're at the very least less visually distracting. You can also be pretty sure that they will render the same for everyone. Again, this is for SO meta, on main they're in the same category as thanks and please.

Comment: @AkselA Me too, but I wanted to point that if smiles are not welcomed here, then emojis should be avoided too.

Comment: @Stijn: Whoah, thanks! Thoughts and prayers to you too

Comment: I'm conditioned to expect emojis now by years of daily aggressive exposure, it makes an article like the data science one more palatable.

Comment: They add no value. Burninate them all.

Comment: I had completely blanked them, and didn't notice them at all ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: IMHO it just made the post look childish/unprofessional... not sure what the point was. TBH, I don't even get what 60% of those emoticons were supposed to mean.

Comment: It feels as though this was a poor attempt at being "young" or "hip" and it definitely doesn't work. It just detracts from what might possibly be a good post.

Comment: @Stijn Excellent example of how implementation-dependent emojis are. Rendered in Google Chrome on Windows 10, I see (in order) [a grey hand, a rectangle, two ?elephant men/tentacle-faced aliens? in blue suits, two more aliens, a yellow trophy, Trogdor's arm, a man a woman, a girl, a boy, an extremely small red triangle and another rectangle](https://imgur.com/a/QLd5DbJ). (Without context, I would not have recognized the girl or boy and one could probably be forgiven for mistaking the woman as a canoe on fire.)

Comment: @jmbpiano all the grey makes it look so sad :P [perhaps you're running an older version of Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptOVB.png)? Oh and Jeroen, I'll send you the essay in 6 to 8 weeks ;)

Comment: We must keep it, they are both funny and cute.

Comment: I find your lack of humour disturbing  

Comment: they determined adding emoji's makes the post more welcoming. whatever that means.

Comment: Ban them outright as far as I'm concerned. This is a programming Q&A site, not a teenage text chat. </oldgit>

Comment: It's important to remember that emojis are inaccessible to some, so you should never use them to convey *actual content*, only as decoration.  (The referenced post complies with that.)  @Stijn's message, to me, is: hello, yellow-and-blue-thing, and welcome, is-that-a-frown?wtf? to Stack Overflow! praying-hands? praying-hands  (Wait, am I going to need divine assistance to continue?)

Comment: Is there a question or suggestion here or are you just stating your opinion?

Comment: Does the "Data science time!" post need all the emojis it has? No, it comes off as noise.  But banning them outright is going to make legitimate questions ***about*** emojis difficult.

Comment: Lets argue about emojis being legal, that sounds reasonable, people expressing themselves is a bad thing, yeah let's ban that because i cannot stand 4 emojis in a page long post i absolutely cannot ignore them and/or look away i will perish if i keep looking at it ban it. Sounds reasonable.

Comment: "Triggered" doesn't refer to just being angry, upset, or disturbed. When used unironically, it refers to PTSD "triggers," which are phrases or imagery that causes flashbacks to the trauma (usually violence or sexual assault related to powerlessness) in question. Many consider the casual use of it rude, flippant, and/or insensitive to those with PTSD because it can come across as making light of trauma. In other words, it's not exactly simple "kids' [or Millennials'] lingo."

Comment: @Stijn I'm sorely disappointed that SO doesn't have an emoji.

Comment: @ivan surely the same could be said about other rules that were put in place through meta discussions like this such as the stance on salutations. It isn't about sounding or being unreasonable, it is about getting to the point and emojis in this case don't help, they distract at best and confuse at worst.

Comment: @zero298 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381660/can-we-stop-emojis-being-a-part-of-question-titles - About the title but the points raised could be extended everywhere. I guess it goes back to what I said, include if needed, remove if not.

Comment: +1. I freaking hate emojis

Comment: I definitely thought that the data science post was trying to sell me weight-loss wraps or keto coffee.

Comment: @Script47 While i agree with that i feel that all of this is just people hating on emoji's existence rather than actually being a problem, plus its making a fuzz over just one post that was entirely fine. It seems like an useless discussion i feel like if we are going to ban emojis and everything non-serious that doesn't add anything to a post, lets remove joke comments, avatars, usernames that are not real names, hell why even have a bio or badges if its irrelevant for a Q & A site? Some people like emojis, some don't. Don't make a fuzz over it.

Comment: @ivan if you look back at the 'data science' posts, they consistently have emojis. As far as making a 'fuzz' goes, using meta to discuss something is not making a 'fuzz', it's using meta for its intended purpose. Comments that aren't related to a post should be me removed, I have no qualms with that. As for the rest, they have nothing to do with posts, they are more to do with user engagement I suppose.

Comment: @Script47 Discussion in meta is the point of the whole site, which is why i am giving my opinion, and i just think this whole post is a joke, the 2nd top answer is a joke, And the ones supporting the "Emoji's ban" seem to have fairly weak points "childish"/"unprofessional"/"doesn't add anything to the question", you cannot *force* everyone to be professional and not "childish", if you don't like it well then too bad i guess, but while it is true that it doesn't add anything to a post, it doesn't take anything away either, but banning free expression is a pretty big deal.

Comment: @ivan: I'm doing free hugs at the moment, if that would help? `:=]`

Comment: @ivan this site already bans/is against many forms of free expression and it's a good thing too. This isn't about freedom of speech or expression as your comment indicates, this is about how you should conduct yourself on a site which has rules and regulations and the author is trying to get a precedent set.

Comment: @Script47 The only thing i have seen in the FAQ that "bans" forms of free expression, is just Out of topic things which is normal im not going to ask how to avoid shield pressure in a coding community, and being unfriendly which is also normal in any kind of community, aside from that there are no ban's. 
I am aware the site has its rules, the consideration of adding this as a rule is just not worth even the thought. The abuse of emojis as shown in the answers and comments here as a parody is the only case worth considering.

Answer (score 64):

I hear what you are saying and am thinking hard about it. My robot companion has forwarded your concerns on to the team and we will be sure to take it into consideration when composing future messages and announcements.

For now, here is a castle made of bananas:

Want to write obnoxious messages but don't hang with the kids? I recommend [https://lingojam.com/EmojiTranslator](https://lingojam.com/%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BDEmojiTranslator%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD) - "It's unlinkable!"

Comment: 

Comment: Is there a ️ link  that works in reverse◀️? I tried copying your post  into the Emoji side and it didn't go ⬅️ back  to plain English. (by the way ↕️, +1  for the castle )

Comment: @astonearachnid I regret reading that comment.

Comment: Perfect tool to use while writing flag decline messages ...

Comment: This is the best answer. Not only you take action, it also has a banana castle. 

Comment: [](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170699/bananas-in-comments#comment1076045_170803)

Comment: Never before have I seen such a magnificent banana castle.

Comment: Aside from the obvious lack of professionalism and wrong tone that the use of emojis conveys, there is a very real usability problem. [This is what your answer looks like on my work computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djBZF.png). Half of it is just white boxes. The other half is, of course, bananas, which I guess I can't really complain about.

Comment: Oh yeah, I get some of those too. Also looks completely different on each machine. Uh. 

Comment: dude--y no blinking?! otoh why bother w/ all those caps & wordywords & grammr & splg? & why no hi n bye, dont u wanna b nice?

Comment: Related: The now classic [`kbd` castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-too-intrusive/1974#1974) (cross-site) (breaks at high zoom levels).

Answer (score 53):

Of all the things to be upset about in that post...a smattering of emojis used in certain places is probably the *least* significant thing to be bothered about.

It isn't like the post is drowning in them, nor is it the case that they're used offensively or excessively.

I wouldn't bother with this one; there's really no benefit to it.  There are other things to edit out on Meta that don't involve <s>needlessly</s> editing an employee's post.

Comment: Fair, but I assume the question is not "should we edit this particular question" but more "Do we include emojis in our standard of a good meta post?". Fine, leave this one as it is, to avoid conflict. Please, I'd rather they not write the next one with emojis.

Comment: @AnderBiguri:  And if they did, seriously, is it *that* big of a deal?  How much more paint do we need to apply to this bikeshed before we turn our attention to the big ol' crack in the cooling tower?

Comment: @Makoto: I heard it was the lead paint they used on the bikeshed that caused the fumes that eroded the metal in the cooling tower.

Comment: @Makoto, I'm not trying to make a big deal out of it, I agree with your approach. It would not be desastrous at all, but well, I rather they don't. Nothing more than that, I just prefer this not to be standard. Not trying to get a pitchfork or anything.

Answer (score 31):

> I don't want to discourage the use of emojis outright, but rather encourage a carefully considered use.

Sure, that sounds reasonable. Anything else?

---

Ultimately, if someone (mod or otherwise) wants to jam a bunch of emojis in a post, I don't really care.

Yes, it can make it harder to take seriously, and yes, I can't help but roll my eyes 180° until I've blinded myself, but it's not something worth fussing over.

I most certainly don't support MilkyWay's extreme stance of:

> we should NOT allow emojis

If people keep making posts with a bunch of emojis and users don't take those posts 
seriously as a result, well, then hopefully the posters will learn their lesson and stop using as many emojis.

**We don't need any hard rules about this. People should simply use their best judgement.**

Comment: Ok, you don't care either way, but there are others that do care. I personally think that it makes the posts harder to read and therefore is an accessibility issue at the very least. I think "I don't care" is not a considerate response here, it actually seems fairly lazy and insulting to those of us who do care.

Comment: "Ultimately, if someone (mod or otherwise) wants to jam a bunch of emojis in a post, I don't really care." That is what I'm taking issue with. Also the "not something worth fussing over"

Answer (score 21):

I didn't even notice the emojis until it was pointed out here. I guess I filter out emojis like that because they actually add no content to the post, which I suppose is part of the problem. What is the purpose of literally just copying what you just said and trying to translate it into emoji (tumbleweed =  hurricane plus wheat now I guess).  This isn't even how people text emojis.  Just comes off as forced, out of touch, and it's just noisy.

That being said while I agree some one could probably construe this as unprofessional, to me this is more silly than anything.  Looks like the kind of language a company community manager would use when sending out an invite to the annual company potluck, and not anything really out of the ordinary for a company representative.

What we *reaally* shouldn't do is make a big fuss about this and raise our pitchforks against this harmless out of touch use of emojis. And we **really don't want to target this individual in particular**, who at this point appears to be the only one doing this.

I don't think it is worth our time to complain about this, StackOverflow as a company already has a hard time taking meta seriously with our *actual* issues.  What do you think is going to happen when every-time someone makes a typo, or some minor formatting issue the whole community gets in an uproar?

Comment: I was kind of in the same boat; "Wait, there were emojis there?" I just filter them out when reading.

Answer (score 12):

## Yes, we should NOT allow emojis

First, no, I'm not what you guys would call old. I just fail to understand the use of emojis on a serious Q&A site.

Emojis, while handy for expressing emotion, don't add *anything* to a question. There is no need to express thoughts through emojis when you can use text because emojis aren't recognized worldwide (some of them, at least).

However, there are always exceptions. Questions about emoji domain names, programs which use emojis, or esoteric programming languages that use emojis should be allowed.

Comment: I find it unusually amusing that this answer was written by someone who chose to take on the username MilkyWay90 with an avatar that is really close to an emoji.

Comment: @Gimby It's my Geometry Dash characters (or former character). My username came from when I was in 1st grade and had no idea about emojis.

Comment: I am not sure emojis are unprofessional but if you do consider that being or looking unprofessional as a reason for not being on Stack Overflow wouldn't that also include a lot of usernames and avatars as well? A more appropriate reason for not allowing them would be that they don't add anything of value to a question or answer.

Comment: I'd like to point out that in some cases the use of emojis might be necessary in questions and answers. Think about questions relating [punycode domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji_domain) or [evil programming languages](https://www.emojicode.org/). The usage of emojis to express emotions will probably rarely have any added value on this platform.

Comment: @Wouter Yes, I am aware of emoji-related domains and esoteric programming languages. of course there are exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

This whole thread is not a good look for inclusion in tech.

Stack Overflow's user base is 90% male according to the annual survey. And here we have users writing a post and replies to police the communication style of a female employee, annoyed that she used a whole *five* emoji in a blog post. Does that aspect not jump out at anyone else?

Communication in general is gendered, and this includes emojis. Norms and patterns concerning emoji use vary by gender and by Internet subcultures. For instance, women have been found to be more likely to use emoji. Emoji use is widespread on the [#rstats](https://twitter.com/hashtag/rstats?lang=en) Twitter hashtag - a professional space where this author collaborates - and is even more frequent within the well-regarded RLadies community of female data scientists, also a professional space. For example, look for emoji in the posts of https://twitter.com/rladiesglobal.

This seems to be Julia's authentic communication style and it's valid within many online professional spaces. If it's not how *you* prefer to express yourself, or the style in *your* professional spaces, just let it go. It's different, not wrong.

Non-emoji-using developers may find the post "[The Minimally Nice Maintainer](http://brson.github.io/2017/04/05/minimally-nice-maintainer)" interesting, which makes a good case for why more developers should start using emoji as they collaborate on open-source. See the section "Be Effusive". It took the author a while to realize that in his open-source communication, emojis were a valuable tool, conveying meaning that words could not.

Lastly, it was unnecessary to mock the idea of "triggered" as something "the kids" say these days. An example of actual triggering would be a soldier with PTSD being shown war footage that brings back the traumatic experience they suffered. It's a real thing; joking about it starts this off on the wrong foot.

Comment: Though I agree the post is a little fussy, and I don't know why we need to argue about emoji use, your comment about how we're policing the communication style of a *female* bothered me. What does her being a female have to do with this? A guy could just as well write a post with a bunch of emojis, and people could take it poorly. "not looking good for inclusion" - oh please

."seems to be her authentic communication style" - ok, and who cares. If my authentic communication style was to insert curse words at the end of every sentence, would it be wrong for people to have a problem with it?

Comment: The use of 'triggered' to mean being caused to take action, has been around longer than the concept of PTSD. I was hoping we could avoid making this personal, there's no need for that.

Comment: Just like OP, I think emojis in that context are a bit silly and unprofessional. I didn't care enough about it to make a Meta post, but I still feel personally attacked by your answer and I take great offence at your accusation of sexism.

Comment: I edited out the offending word.

Comment: Of course we police content and we've always done so (formatting, salutation rules, thanking in posts and comments, general noise) because if we don't then we get all kinds of mess. Why would emojis be different?

Comment: An interesting take. Not that I'm necessarily opposed to a change of culture, but the "be effusive" advice seems directly at odds with SO's "minimalist" take on question language, where even saying "Thanks in advance" at the end of your question will be edited away, so I'm not sure I agree with the Twitter analogues being relevant. However, the difference in language by gender (which I wasn't aware of) certainly is. @Stijn and others would do well to remember that sexism doesn't need to be intentional, it only needs to be discriminatory or exclusive. Impact matters more than intent.

Comment: @Stijn, there is a "flag" link at the end of the answer you can use if it's too offensive or if you're being attacked.

Comment: As a woman in tech, #rstats user myself, linguist by training, and (of course) huge fan of Dr. Silge's work and influence I'm thankful for your response, Sam.

Comment: "emojis were a valuable tool, conveying meaning that words could not".  No.  The meaning can be conveyed using words.  Emojis change the building blocks of communication from objective (meaning) to subjective (feeling).  Unfortunately they also greatly increase ambiguity and opportunity for confusion in the process, doubly so when using Unicode emojis which are not presented the same way to every viewer.

Comment: If my natural communication style is to pepper my speech with expletives, then [Stack Exchange is not very inclusive of me and my communication style](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites), either. Even though that might be my authentic communication style, accepted in certain communities, and an important part of what I consider to be my "identity". Which is why this is not an inclusivity issue; it's a professionalism one.