# New home page makes it seem like SO doesn't allow free use any more

Tags: discussion, homepage, anonymous-user

I will start off by saying that I'm a bit of an oddball. I browse exclusively in private browsing mode. When I'm logged in to Stack Overflow and close a tab, I'm no longer logged in. So despite being a regular, I log in manually every day.

Today before I logged in I saw the new home page, and it immediately felt the same to me as going to Facebook or LinkedIn before you have an account. There's a big wall of gibberish that essentially says, "You can't do anything here until you start handing over information about yourself."

I clicked on the "For Developers" button and it scrolled down the page to show me products. I'm not looking for products. I'm looking to get questions answered. After scrolling through all of it, there was no content I actually wanted to see. Where did the questions and answers go?

Now, being a long-time user, I can just log in to see the questions. But being curious, I clicked around and found you can click on the hamburger menu and then click "Stack Overflow" to get to the questions. That is not at all obvious, and I doubt most new users will try that.

In all, this feels very unwelcoming for new users. I can understand the need to tell the world about the great products Stack Overflow provides. (We even use them at my workplace.) But this feels like the wrong way to do it. It also feels like advertising to the wrong people. I don't have any control over whether my workplace buys your products. I just want to get my questions answered.

Comment: Related, maybe dupe: [Faster access to questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386495/4642212).

Comment: Related, but I think we're getting at different things. One part is how to quickly get to the questions, but the bigger thing for me is that it doesn't seem like there are any questions anymore. It seems like a walled garden that you have to pay (with information) to access now (even though it's not).

Comment: Can we stop calling everything 'unwelcoming'? If you believe the new page is hard to navigate and advertising to the wrong people, say that.

Comment: I'm trying to point out that the web site is not achieving one of its stated goals, so I'm using their wording.

Comment: I see "unwelcoming" on a Meta post anymore and I instantly get _so_ triggered behind it...yeah, the screen is crowded, and *quite* noisy, but ***unwelcoming***?  Really?

Comment: Well, feel free to edit. I didn't intend to trigger anyone. I honestly thought that word expressed what I was trying to say in a way this community would understand. It kind of felt like: "When I come here, it no longer seems like it's for what I intended to do here. It looks like you have to spend money here to do stuff, and people wanting free help are no longer welcome to use it." So yes, I really meant "unwelcoming". But if that's the new trigger word, then substitute whatever you feel better describes this scenario.

Comment: Well...I don't want to put words in your mouth @user1118321.  If you feel like it's unwelcoming to you, so be it.  If you didn't *mean* that, then you may want to consider another phrase to describe what you're seeing and how you're reacting to it.  Who knows - maybe "unwelcoming" is spot on.

Comment: I've clarified with the hopes that it will guide the discussion towards the actual question and not get us hung up on wording.

Comment: It seems that the choice we made in describing Stack Overflow is unclear. We refer to our sites as "Public Q&A" but that's not necessarily how y'all refer to it - maybe we can revisit that phrasing. "Public Q&A" **is** SO. If you click on "free community" in that box, you'll go straight to the questions page. Is there a way we could clarify this?

Comment: I just tried a private window. I agree with the part that it's not obvious how to reach the Q&A without 1) creating an account or 2) paying. However, I did quickly find 2 ways to do so.

Comment: @Catija As a new user, I'm not going to read anything. Making me click a button to get to the content is the problem. Think of it this way - when I go to a news web site, I automatically ignore the banner ads because they have never provided anything useful to me in almost 30 years of web surfing. It's the same with the design of the new home page. I'm not even going to read it. If I see buttons, that means it leads to entering personal information, which I'm not going to do for a free Q&A site. I see a button and I immediately scroll past it out of habit.

Comment: it's simply not possible to re-see it as a new user. we can claim how a new user would see it, but without actually having new users do it... all we can really look at is the results of it. It's highly unlikely that someone will find SO for the first time by visiting the home page. I don't like how hard the side services are being pushed over the Q&A, but that's just my preference. I don't particular care for the career tool, and have no use for teams... and will likely never see that new home page unless i specifically try to access it. Just don't replace the logged in home page.

Comment: Many (most?) new users will get to Stack Overflow via results in a search engine, so this may not be as big a problem you think.

Comment: @Catija: I think the problem is in this statement: "*"Public Q&A" is SO.*" No, ***SO*** is SO. You're trying to create the notion that SO is bigger than or otherwise distinct from Q&A, but it's not. At least, that's not how most people see it. To most people, the Q&A site is what SO is; Teams, Careers, whatever else are *additions*, sideshows to the main attraction. The main product, the reason why we're here, is Stack Overflow. SO is not bigger than Q&A; it *is Q&A*. The best way to clarify how to get to SO's Q&A site is to stop getting in the way of people trying to get to SO's Q&A site.

Comment: @NicolBolas  I'm not actually saying that SO is bigger than Q&A. I'm saying that what we call "Public Q&A" in that box **is** the question and answer site, "Stack Overflow". ... it's exclusive of Teams, Business & Enterprise (Private Q&A) and from Jobs, which are in the other two boxes. I said exactly what you just said. But, we as a company that is also called "Stack Overflow" have several products, of which one is what we refer to as "Public Q&A"... and that term may not be as comprehensible to people outside the company...

Comment: Wow, does it ever make it seem that way. I just accidentally landed on this after getting logged out on mobile. I had previously felt that [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386324), while it had an undeniable ring of truth, was a bit of an overreaction. I no longer feel that way. I feel duped, taken advantage of, and embarrassed about my association with this platform.

Comment: I guess that most users do not get to the site via the homepage. But it is still kinda kinda weird UX to click on a [menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu5F3.png) that says _"Products -> Stack Overflow - Public questions and answers"_ and to be taken to another section of the same page where you can make **the same choice... again**. Whereas the menu items "Teams" and "Enterprise" actually take you to the appropriate place directly. I'm sure there is no ill will behind this, and old hands can learn to go directly to `/questions` or use the hamburger menu... but it's still a curious choice.

Comment: I can't believe I'm the only person who wondered what "We less than three people who code" meant.  We're developers we don't do cuddly.

Comment: Well I just learn about this new home page. I click the log out button. And it was a nightmare. I had to use history to get back to this question and use people comment to find the way.

Comment: this MSE discussion seems related: [Can we show new/anonymous users more Q&A?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314134/165773)

Comment: @SList [ sorry you're unhappy ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386228/for-a-more-considered-use-of-emojis)

Comment: @xdtTransform I had the same in incognito. I just wanted to see the list of questions. Took me a minute to find a way to it, but I was already starting to panic that the front front page was blocking off any and all avenues to the question list.

Comment: @Tschallacka, Going back now feels like a magic trick, with misdirection and "trompe l'oeil". Every magic trick need a good story and some kind of misdirection. We ended up on this page. It's a nice new page, and we begin to tell ourself the story: "I just need to scroll a little to find the ..  "-- Magic happens-- "Did the question disappear? Like a coin in a magician hand?" --Climax music-- "*Shook, and horror* Paywall? What's going on? How do I go back?".. That's David Copperfiel making question and user base disappear.

Comment: @SList simple, this means "We fired all but 2 developers" - and hired 100  MBAs in Marketing instead. Welcome to the new SO.

Comment: @Arkadiy ha ha probably!

Comment: Also, "We <3 people who code" is so early-2010s. It should be "We ❤️ people who code". ;) err... I mean 

Comment: @Catija If you're really serious about improving it, then I have some recommendations. **1)** reduce the size of the hero banner by ~50%. **2)** Remove the "for developers, by developers" section and have the "*Developers*" button at the top go straight to https://stackoverflow.com/questions. **3)** Remove the section on SO for Teams pricing -- that belongs as a click-through page via the "*Private Q&A*" link on the "For business by developers" section. On that subject, "*Private Q&A*" should say "*Teams (Private Q&A)*".  **4)** Remove redundant `.talent-slope` div and `.py64` div below it

Comment: @Catija Follow-up on reasoning for removing redundant sections: The `.talent-slope` section is just an exact duplication of links to SO for Business Talent and Ads that exist in the section immediately prior. Likewise, the big `.py64` section on signing up for Q&A should belong somewhere *after* you click the "sign up" button (without the "create an account" button, of course, as that'd be redundant even at that stage).

Comment: **Holy crap**.  That's even worse than the [hyphenated site](https://www.experts-exchange.com/).

Comment: @Catija Also I'm sure you are aware but the "Teams" branding is also inherently problematic; aside from the awkwardness of referring to a "Teams team", Microsoft also has a product (which came to market earlier than SO Teams, IIRC) called Teams, and they're, well, bigger than Stack Overflow. So it's probably a good idea to keep a focus group churning on good replacement names. But I know naming things is one of the hardest problems in programming, too :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Welcome to the party. I mean, sorry that you've now found yourself sharing this depressing, sad position with way too many formerly active users.

Comment: Do all "hot meta questions" disappear from sidebar when they hit hundred upvotes or is this quesion special?

Comment: @TylerH YES! thank you for adding the concrete suggestions. I think those are all very productive ideas!

Comment: @Arkadiy New SO?  SO has had almost no developers working on it for like 10 years (if we're talking about the Q/A portion of the product).  They pull people off of other projects here and there to fix bugs, or to do a short odd or end, but there hasn't been a large dedicated Q/A developer team in like 10 years.

Comment: I'm about to do a lunch-learn on why we should contribute to SO and how. When I get to the part about navigating, I was going to say that it's self-explanatory. I haven't looked in a while. It's not. I'll have to guide them through it. Ignore this, select that option, etc. I hate to be harsh, but one of the worst things you can say about a site's navigation is that you need someone to tell you how to navigate it. Maybe someone should ask for help [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yeah the new splash page is pretty awful.  It no longer feels like a Q&A site, and does very much communicate "no account? you can't use SO".  Are we going to have to pay for SO soon?  If so count me out.

Comment: Yeah, why is the "Public Q&A" box's button "Create an account", and not just "Go to Q&A"?

Comment: @Blorgbeard that was an easy one to address, so we changed it already :) more updates soon from Cesar.

Comment: With all the concern about SO's direction and values that's been going on lately, this seems like a spectacularly and bafflingly inappropriate moment to choose for making such a predictably offensive change to the site. It's a real head scratcher.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths add a [front-page link to the newest controversial and off-topic question that's actually locked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARm5x.png) to broadcast complete disregard for the quality of the site [that so many are concerned with](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386324/the-stack-overflow-i-wish-to-build-and-participate-in-is-no-longer-supported). The more answers and comments I read here the less I can imagine them being able to make this any worse for themselves. Imagine one of those memes where the guy who has the only good suggestion gets thrown out the window...

Comment: Andras, *please don't tell that to @Makoto*

Comment: @Kreiri That list rotates automatically -- I'm sure they did not remove it explicitly; much worse threads have been up there in the past and not removed.

Comment: @TylerH however putting that question on homepage?, heck I even defended it to not be deleted, but yeah now I'm not sure if it's just hilarious or if they are just....

Comment: @PetterFriberg If you mean the curl one, I'm sure that is just the natural result of the years-long divide between the values of Meta and the values of the people running the company. As much as I may agree, it's probably best not to try and rehash that subject here.

Comment: @TylerH Probably, but in the middle let's atleast have knowledge and respect

Comment: @TylerH I disagree. This is all about the company having pipe dream visions of where the company should go when their only product that's publicly visibly successful is Q&A. Trying to hide Q&A in shame and pushing all the other (often half-baked) products is exactly what I seem to see on the new Q&A-free front page, and this has everything to do with "the values of the people running the company".

Comment: I think what looks even worse is that the bit of description shown in a Google search only refers to [their product](https://imgur.com/ZywRi0T).

Comment: @rla4 Thank you for the change. That is a nice improvement over the previous actions needed to get to the Q&A, though I still think more needs to be done.

Comment: Lets not be hyperbolic. There is a problem regarding navigation. Tell it to the developers. Give feedback and then it will be solved. No need to use hyperbolic terms.

Comment: maybe it's just that age old adage, you become the thing you hate. Sounds more like experts-exchange.com which SO was created to replace.

Comment: @gman the similarity of the frontpages is uncanny.

Comment: I propose we vote to close this site as "Unclear of what you are asking". I also vote to close the vote to close option of "Unclear of what you are asking" because do we even ask questions here anymore? UI doesn't seem to think so.

Comment: @SList I've just gotten into the habit of reading "<3" as "teabag" (except, well, more explicit in my head)

Comment: It’s a new form of test. The assumption is new users who can’t find their way to the Q&A are probably the same users that leave off topic questions so clearly the new home page is by design … wink wink … he wrote sarcastically

Comment: Would that be [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/) ?? I see only questions there, no ads, no banner..

Comment: @TaW log out...

Comment: @Andras: I feel dumb, but how do I do that?

Comment: That new design is awesome. It scares away many new users that were to ask a terribad question. Only those clever enough to unlock the free option will proceed. That should drive question quality up. Isn't that what we all asked for? Let's keep this  for 6 to 8 weeks and then look at the data. If the quality of first posts improved I would call it a win and then demand it is kept, even if the conversion rates tell the marketeers otherwise.

Comment: @TaW easiest way is opening a porn mode ("private browsing") window in your browser.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well it looks flashy but it took two clicks to proceed to the questions: 'For developers' and 'public q&a'.

Comment: I'm a bit torn about this issue. **Pro:** It's becoming harder for new users to actually join the site and ask questions. Yes, that's a **pro**, because I assume that many of the VLQ posts came from users who are now kept out by the necessity to actually *read* and *understand* a written procedure and follow the right links (you may call this "unwelcoming" - but I think that's fine...). **Con**: The time, effort and money that has been invested into "brand managers" and "designers" here might have better been invested in developers, e.g. to improve the mod tools. Maybe the effect is the same.

Comment: Okay guys. it's the end of SO. time to create a new true community.

Comment: I addition to what everyone else already said: Why is the “All Questions” list at `/questions` the only/primary list for anonymous users even? The default view there is “Newest questions” which is very irrelevant for anonymous users since they cannot learn anything about the site there but just have a higher likelihood to see bad questions (without answers). Why isn’t the a “Top Questions” list for everybody that highlights interesting content and shows how the site actually works?

Comment: It’s also telling that the website that once stood out boldly by focusing solely on its content and its own mission statement now made the start page for new users look like *every other website* today with a standard hero image, 3 column “feature highlights”, and lots of marketing stuff many visitors don’t actually care about.

Comment: New users don't use the login page at all, they just google a question and go directly to one of the results.

Comment: @TaW Ironic that you had to ask how to logout because it's so unclear

Comment: @MarcosFernandez No they don't bother Googling it or researching, they just ask it again. Badly. To do that presumably they start at the homepage

Comment: @Light: It is more than unclear; it is unresolved. Opening a private window is not at all the same as 'logging out'. Looks like one can't. [Hotel California](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=16&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwig2bqS75PjAhXHy6QKHfnvBhMQwqsBMA96BAgIEAo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D5wDfiCDoHy4&usg=AOvVaw1kmNDKywL-3nLHwmZxrVjz) comes to mind.. Which may actually be the answer to another [prominent post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386639/why-do-you-stay) : _You can check out any time you like. But you can never leave!_ ;-)

Comment: @TaW: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aebNI.png?

Comment: Has this been deliberately excluded from Hot Meta Posts or am I being too paranoid?

Comment: @OrangeDog It seems to come and go. It's been up there a few times and fallen off a few times.

Comment: @TaW Maybe I'm missing something here, but there is a "log out" in the hamburguer ...

Comment: The only thing you missed is Lightning's comment with an image of that very menu :-) - Thanks anyway!

Comment: This question and [one other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386584/why-is-the-popular-how-much-research-effort-is-expected-answer-deleted) consumed my entire daily quota of comment up votes on meta. For the first time ever. Wow, just wow...

Comment: @Makoto It's not unwelcoming in the sense SO staff uses the word, but it is actually unwelcoming. Personally, I sometimes use the word to point out how hypocritical the staff has gotten and point out issues that are actually legitimately unwelcoming even though it isn't what they mean by the word.

Comment: @jpmc26 - very good point that goes right to the nub of a lot of problems, in SO and across the western world.

Comment: The homepage itself sort of openly tells the visitor that the site is unwelcoming - note the `<_/_welcome>` tag on the skyscraper antenna ...

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/cdxl9v/huh/ based on this reddit thread, most outsiders (that post there) do not seem to have a problem with the homepage, and some learned about services. This surprised me a bit.

Comment: I've removed this "Welcoming" tag again, as this is clearly not aimed at being more "Welcoming" to new users.

Comment: @Cerbrus - The OP summarizes the post like this: "*In all, this feels very **unwelcoming** for new users.*" To me, that's a pretty clear indication that they are taking issue with welcoming-ness of the new home page. Can you please explain how you came to the conclusion that this is "*clearly not aimed at being more Welcoming*"?

Comment: On the tag's description: _"Use this for discussions about potential policy changes, and not to deal with specific incidents (except as mentioned as part of broader discussions)."_ This isn't a "Policy" change. This is a design issue, @billynoah.

Comment: @Cerbrus - I beg to differ.  The design of the new home page has everything to do with policy.  Design and policy can't really be extricated from one another in general and this certainly isn't a specific incident (like a one off comment on a thread). Can that OP please chime in here?  I don't want to get in an edit war but I'm dumbfounded that a post which explicitly calls in to question how SO presents itself to the public as unwelcoming is not suitable for the welcoming tag.

Comment: @Cerbrus - also, you said "*I've removed this "Welcoming" tag again*" - I don't see any prior edit like that in the history? Was the tag there previously?

Comment: @billynoah: The OP didn't feel that the homepage was welcoming. This is not about the "welcoming" movement / blog post. Please read the first couple of comments on here. They explain why "Welcoming" is such a loaded word, nowadays. Re "again": Blame that on English being a second language for me.

Comment: Ok, I did read those comments. Are we really saying that the **welcoming** tag can't be used because it's a "trigger word"?  Sorry but that's ridiculous. The OP even specifically states *I really meant "unwelcoming"* - after the title was edited.  We're not talking about weird color or the width of a sidebar here - we're talking about **content on the homepage that feels unwelcoming**.  I don't care if that triggers people but to me that's a very apt description and it fits the tag.

Comment: No, I'm saying it doesn't apply here because this is a question about the homepage design, and not about the "welcoming" policy.

Comment: Jeff Atwood would never, EVER have approved this.

Answer (score -222, accepted):

It was not our intention to hide or make it harder to access the public, open Q&A. Our values around this have not changed.

We will be making tweaks in the current design to make it clearer and easier to get the public questions without having to register for an account.

Overall changes in design will not be made at this moment (we are still collecting the feedback you are all posting - thanks for that). And we are carefully reviewing it and will make them later if it's necessary, however, we do want to make it easier to get to the open Q&A as fast as possible, and that means not changing the design right now.

I'm not touching on the other points intentionally, because I want to first address the biggest point which is: It's hard to get to Q&A right now, and that doesn't mean we are ignoring everything else, though.

**Update 1:**
To address the immediate concern, for now, we've hyperlinked the "Open Community" in the description and made the big blue button link directly to the questions, de-emphasizing the Sign-Up button to in-text hyperlink.

**Update 2:** We've made the old homepage accessible through the magicurl ?questions. So going to [stackoverflow.com/?questions](https://stackoverflow.com/?questions) should take anonymous users to the old homepage. This isn't a homepage improvement yet, but something I'd like people to be aware of still.

[image: Homepage showing updated buttons]

Comment: Was it really necessary to work on a homepage redesign when the community [is waiting for some improvements to the user moderation tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285889/311398). I get it that the push is towards showing that Stack Overflow is no longer just a Q&A site but also includes private spaces and jobs, but some improvements in the Q&A area would be nice.

Comment: Barring that, is there at least a roadmap of some sort showing company priorities to moderation tools?  We're left to react to changes that are surprises, and leave your long term users feeling like they're ignored.  Knowing that there's something in the pipeline addressing their concerns would go a long way to alleviating that issue.

Comment: @BhargavRao the resources for those two efforts are non-competing. It's not taking time off from Community team developers. We are still committed to delivering improvements to Q&A including mod tools. We also plan on delivering a sort of roadmap and improving communication around what we have planned for those improvements.

Comment: Well, that's a bit reassuring, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you want to emphasize more the search aspect of the Q&A, rather than the list of crap that was the previous homepage, maybe a search box would be more palatable.

Comment: @Braiam ah, yes, the famously good internal search engine of Stack Overflow. (Not.)

Comment: @AndrasDeak at least it would be a clear path to Q&A.

Comment: Updated the answer with the change we made today.

Comment: Thanks for the change, but I don't believe it "address[es] the immediate concern". As long as you need a red free-hand circle to find the actual Q&A from stackoverflow.com the front page has failed its task.

Comment: You might consider switching the places of Private Q&A and Public Q&A. With Private QA being directly below some other centered text and being raised above the other two choices, it is seen first. Given that people who come to SO generally want to see the questions it seems like that should the option with highest precedence, with everything else there as alternatives

Comment: @AndrasDeak While it may not be optimal, it is definitely an improvement. And considering this question has been open less than a day, we can't really expect them to have redesigned the entire home page yet. A good intermediate step, until a more through redesign can be done.

Comment: Of course priorities compete, eventually every person-hour is paid out of the same account and the person who controls that account decides to prioritize som tasks and ignore others. If you have hired an army of SEO professionals or marketing people and sacked your developers and community managers, that's a clear prioritization too.

Comment: @CesarM Thank you, these two changes do go a fair way toward making it easier to find the Q&A as a passive/anonymous reader.

Comment: While I appreciate making ability to visit programming questions *more* visible that it was this morning I don't think it is enough. *Main* purpose of this site was (and I hope still is) to be repository of *easily* searchable programming questions and answers. Because we believed in that great idea we devoted quite amount of our time (read life) to build and take care of this repository. So I can't agree with making 90% of *main* page into an advertisement for *any* product(s). That is not what this site was for so please don't go that way.

Comment: I just visited SO while not logged in for the first time since this change and I'm still confused how to see the questions. Well, ok, there's the top left menu, where I can click on “Stack Overflow”. So to reach Stack Overflow I have to go to Stack Overflow and then click on a hidden Stack Overflow. Not very intuitive. The “open community” link? You're asking me to read the small print, and to click a link which I'd expect to go to an “about this community” page and not to the actual site?

Comment: *(cont.)* I guess the most obvious way to reach SO is the “Browse questions” in the “Public Q&A” box, but it's pretty low on discoverability: you have to find a button in a box below the fold. The impression I get is that you're preparing to shut down SO, and this is the first step in driving users way from it. Which wouldn't make be confident if I was considering purchasing a private instance: are you preparing to go out of business?

Comment: Thank you for these changes! I feel they're a good start and show a good faith effort to address our concerns. I agree with others that they aren't complete enough, but I do appreciate that you were willing to make this changes as quickly as you did.

Comment: You still have to scroll down and there is still an animation fading in the "Browse questions" button. You really should make the "Browse questions" button the most important element. Do not forget, the public site is still the best advertisment for your service. So make it as easy as possible to access the public questions.

Comment: And you're hiding the "Browse questions" Button in a card among two others, looking like how other sites present their plans ("Private Q&A", "Browse questions (most popular)", "Browse jobs"). Place a big red button "Go to StackOverflow" between "For developers" and "For businesses" buttons. And make the buttons less ambigous. I *really* expected the "For developers" button to take me to the questions, when I saw the new site for the first time.

Comment: I just went to the homepage in incognito having read this question for the first time, and was confused as to what the practically problem really was. *As far as I could see, it was easy enough to find questions.* Then I realised that the text "Browse Questions" is brand new since the question was posted. I went back and re-checked the screenshots throughout this question and noticed that it used to be a link to sign-up and agreed that it was bad. Then I saw your answer. **To me, this all shows that the label change was in itself a _significant_ improvement.** Thanks!

Comment: @CesarM, while you're at it, can't you redirect anyone that **is** logged in from the homepage (stackoverflow.com) directly to the far more useful stackoverflow.com/questions?

Comment: The "Stackoverflow" logo at the top left still redirects users to that pay-wall-seeming homepage, if logged off. That's mainly the only way that I use to get to the questions section.

Comment: @allo I think you may have missed your own point "Do not forget, the public site is still the best advertisment for your service" This is exactly what they have designed the landing page to be -- an advertisement for *all* the services that they offer. Q&A doesn't net them money directly. Ads, Teams, and Jobs do, so they're optimizing for that, which makes perfect business sense. That's what a business landing page is *for*. The only issue is that they buried the path to Q&A way too much in the process.

Comment: @Luuklag that has already been the case since always (I have "https://stackoverflow.com" in my bookmarks toolbar and am always logged in -- I've never clicked that and *not* gone to the Q&A page directly).

Comment: @TylerH, the pages look very similar, but if you go to /questions (All Questions), and you opted in for custom questions list, the saved lists are available. They are not available at the mainpage (Top Questions). Differences are subtle though.

Comment: @Luuklag Ah, I see what you mean, the "front page" of questions vs the actual /questions view. I think it would be better if they just renamed the sidebar link to /questions from "Stack Overflow" to "Questions" because why the heck is it not "Questions" already?

Comment: @TylerH My point is, that the Q&A list is the best *advertisment* (showing how good the offer is), not the best way to present the offer (e.g. what services are included and the price tag). So they need to find a space to offer their services and then prominently show the product, i.e, the site itself. Currently the site, that's the best advertisment, is quite well hidden and you only get to see a lot of marketing slogans, that do a much worse job when somebody with tech background should be convinced to buy the product.

Comment: @allo /questions is not a good advertisement at all. It's a huge construct that actually presents a bunch of low-quality, daily-repeated questions to people who look at it. The value of Q&A is entirely opaque until you get to the reports and data in a consumable format *about* Q&A, e.g. "we have this many daily users", etc. A marketer suggesting that the /questions page is the best advertisement for SO should be fired on the spot.

Comment: *"It was not our intention to hide or make it harder to access the public, open QA. Our values around this have not changed."* This is even sadder than I thought. The only conceivable justification for this change was that Stack Overflow is in such dire financial straits that it is going to have to shut its doors if it doesn't drive more people to purchase its products. That wouldn't be good news, but at least it would explain the decision. Instead, what I see here is evidence of utter incompetence. Do you really not see how you've made it nearly impossible to access the public, open Q&A?

Comment: *"Overall changes in design will not be made at this moment."* Well, thanks for at least letting us know where you stand on that. I guess I can stop holding my breath for the Stack Overflow that I knew and loved to return. **This isn't the site that I joined, helped build, and *loved* for so many years. It's no longer a site that I am proud to be associated with.** I have recommended that my coworkers and others stop using it until such time as you decide to re-deploy a site that I am no longer ashamed to be associated with, one that does not hide content behind a paywall or ad banner.

Comment: Since it asked for a comment. it sucks. and it's an incomplete answer. why not touch other parts then ? more like for developers by marketers.

Comment: @user1118321: Can you please accept this answer so that people can find it more easily? It's an official statement from SO, and currently the top N answers are all unofficial "I don't like it" statements (which, although they are generally well thought out and detailed, are nevertheless not particularly helpful to anyone looking for the official response).

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry about that!

Comment: Just went to the homepage in incognito. 3 clicks to get to what the site is all about seems a bit too much.

Comment: @Misguided Not saying it is wonderful or anything. But how does it take you three clicks? Most paths I can see are two clicks, or scroll+click.

Comment: @CodyGray I say this without prejudice at all, honestly, but if that's how you feel and you are actively discouraging others from using the platform, is it appropriate to remain a diamond moderator?

Comment: @CodyGray: If pressing a button is "nearly impossible", then we disagree on what nearly impossible means. Yes - the current design is not 100% ideal and we are working on making the Public QA even easier to access - but to claim that the intent is to hide it away is, in fact, wrong. That said - the homepage is not going away, we are making more changes to it to make it easier to get to public QA, but not removing it. We are also not charging for or demanding that people create accounts for SO, that's not what's happening, so this isn't preparation for a paywall or anything of the sort.

Comment: You have to *find* the button. That's the "nearly impossible" part. I still haven't found the magic entry point. Neither has anyone else that I've talked to or tested the site on. I have, however, found lots of places where Stack Overflow is trying to take my money. Appearances matter---far more than intention, unfortunately. I have to take your word for the fact that the intent is not to hide away Q&A, but that is, in fact, what is happening. You used to go to https://stackoverflow.com, and you would see Q&A. Now you don't. This is far from "not 100% ideal". This is a disappointing watershed.

Comment: Like I said - we will be making changes to the design to make it easier to find. Just not "at this time" as the time of the first update, which was same day as we released it - it might take a little while longer. Once that is done, it should be even easier to access Q&A.

Comment: "we do want to make it easier to get to the open Q&A as fast as possible" - I just cannot fathom how you can say this with a straight face. It was maximally easy and maximally fast to get the open Q&A when **the open Q&A was the homepage**. Literally any change went against your stated goals. You've completely destroyed all trust I has in StackOverflow. You're either supremely incompetent, or supremely evil.

Comment: @CesarM The original version did hide the actual Stack Overflow site very well, the current version still obscures it efficiently by putting the one reasonably visible link among a lot of other stuff. You switched the main site of Stack Overflow the Q&A site with the landing page for SO the company, it's entirely predictable that people are going to be confused, angry and disappointed by this change.

Comment: @OrangeDog: Yes, let me further clarify that: As per my comment above, the homepage will be there, and since that is the case, we want to make it easier to access the open QA within the framework and world where the homepage exists and is there. Mad Scientist: Yes - I understand the frustration and confusion, what I am here to do is say: We understand it was too hard to access QA before, so we improved. Do we think it's 100% there yet? No. So we'll improve it more, we'll make it easier. I just don't have a public when I can commit to especially when people are confused, angry and frustrated.

Comment: Why don't you just undo it and let things as they were, if you want to sell your product you already have https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/. Almost all users (the ones that helped me to become a developer and I value them a lot for that) are feeling used right now, there is nothing wrong in admitting that you people made a mistake

Comment: A huge button which says "Go to Q&A" would have been a more appropriate immediate resolution than just highlighting a text hyperlink.

Comment: @CesarM to be honest, I would rarely think you will persuade any of us. Why? Let's start by a couple of points. #1 from what we can see it's only SO the one that the main page changed. If this was an overall improvement it would apply to all SE family not only to SO. #2 I won't think you are one of the effected people since you are mostly active in other forums and when you login in MSE or BG, you won't see the wall. I agree that Danra could be a solution or split it with Half Questions and Half your promotion if you're not logged in, but if you keep this wall nothing will change.

Comment: @CesarM or you could think in a massive popup with your ad if you haven't logged in, you don't remove any of the options that you have, you only move to a Modal if no action is performed under 30s and you're not logged in. It could be a solution not the best one, but it's better than nothing and you will reduce the backslash.

Comment: Is "Update 2" a joke? In response to the community being upset that you've made Q&A invisible and nigh-inaccessible, you've decided to let us know about a newly introduced ***hidden*** "magic" query string? Anonymous users are not going to find that. **[** Sarcasm removed --Shog. **]**

Comment: @CodyGray it's probably intended as a fix for people who browse SO regularly from the frontpage when logged out, or private window users, et al. Probably also useful for websites or blogs linking to general SO in one context or another, e.g when you want to point your own community there, you could do it using that link and bypass the landing page. But I agree it's not a substantial fix to the problem at hand, although this does have some utility.

Comment: Am I the only one who is irritated by the fact that `https://stackoverflow.com/?questions` leads to the same page as `https://stackoverflow.com/questions` ? I mean, yeah, you can add a question mark in the URL. What's the point?

Comment: @Marco13 that's not the same page, `?questions` doesn't go to the questions page, but the old SO frontpage.

Comment: @MadScientist I tried with a different browser, there might have been some cookie thingy going on, but still, the only real difference seems to be ("All questions" vs. "Top questions", and) the large, blue banner in the `?` case...

Comment: @CodyGray Magisch summed it up pretty well, it's useful for people who want to continue browsing anonymously, albeit only those who are reading this thread. I stated very clearly in the update that this is not homepage related; we will still improve the actual homepage - planning is ongoing for the next revision, and we will be taking the feedback here and elsewhere into account. This quick change was added only as a way to help soften the unintended impact in the interim. **[** Removed some now-irrelevant responses --Shog **]**

Comment: @Marco13, if you are logged in you, will see the same page between stackoverflow.com and stackoverflow.com/?questions whereas stackoverflow.com/questions should be a different page. The ?questions url is a way for logged out people to access the same homepage as logged in people - mainly thinking about users who expressed in this question interest in continue browsing SO logged out or as anonymous, so we made that for easier bookmarking.

Comment: @CesarM and what about the home page tabs like https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured, lets say I know a coworker that could answer some questions there, I pass the link and he sees the paywall, it looks like the people working on this don't know Stack Overflow at all. This just keeps getting worse and worse

Comment: FWIW I like the update. It's straight forward enough to get to the main site and I get what the site is doing, trying to make money on other products from having the main site and it's ok for the company to do that.

Comment: @KacosPro this was not made with making link sharing easier in mind - but rather thinking of people who here asked: "What about users who like to, or have to, browse anonymously who now have to see this every time?". We hoped to improve that. As for your specific question, It's a good one. We've made the homepage bypassable if specific tabs are present. So now you should be able to share that without seeing the homepage.

Comment: @CesarM here's some feedback to take into account: any version of the page that doesn't directly show the Q&A is inacceptable. I would suggest you throw the new homepage away and instead show the questions view again. If you want to push your products into peoples faces, then show a modal dialog on that page which contains some marketing stuff like the "private Q&a" and "jobs" widgets from the current homepage.

Comment: ["I know that this can feel like a nuisance, but we've made this change to make sure we can improve the Stack Overflow experience for users moving forward."](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/6910#issuecomment-398819417)

Comment: I've just noticed this is the case (since usually I'm logged in). In its current form, it is difficult to guess that's the homepage of a questions&answers site that you can use; it looks like the homepage of a company. Unless you change _that_ the page is still broken unfortunately. Can't you move the company-related page to `stackexchange.com` or something?

Comment: The worst is that there is an update and the situation has been extended.

Answer (score 362):

This is pretty bad. Getting to the actual meat (questions) is buried in either a hamburger menu or in a standard marketing type three column structure with lots of graphics and fancy words but nothing to immediately point you there while actual screen real estate is given to all kinds of products.

I thought we wanted to be different from this "Here's all our stuff *and maybe some questions if you ask nicely*" type of nonsense that's so common on the web these days. Yikes.

Your greatest asset is your core Q/A site. Every product you sell (and want to sell more of, understandably) only works and provides value based on the buyer's previous experiences with the Q/A site. I won't buy a team or enterprise instance from your marketing pitch, I might if I use SO regularly and like the structure. I won't use your job board based on your marketing pitch, which makes it sound like Linked In without the clout to pull it off, but I might if I have a profile I put lots of effort into anyways and it gives me a good way to capitalize on that.

Every money making endeavour outside of ads you run is dependant on people understanding and liking the core Q/A system. Therefore it should be in your best interest to put that best foot forward even from a sales perspective, and it definitely should be in the best interest from an ethics perspective.

Please reconsider this design

Comment: Aparently https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314134/can-we-show-new-anonymous-users-more-qa is only for all the other sites. Stack Overflow is the cash cow that needs to be milked it seems.

Comment: Sure, if you still make the mistake of referring to a royal "we" ;) That partnership has ended long ago, the business venture behind Stack Overflow does not know what you are talking about. There are products, a landing page should advertise them. Commercialise website according to modern web design templates: check in the box.

Comment: This seems completely counterproductive to me.  IMO the whole draw of Careers, developer story, etc. was *"You're already here for the Q&A, how about using some other cool tools too?"*  You don't go to the Google homepage and get met with a barrage of "try Adsense" and "buy an Android phone".

Comment: @BJMyers Shhh... don't give Google any ideas.

Comment: It almost seems as if people making that home page don't actually use SO. Welp, I guess we can't have nice things.

Comment: IMHO It's not "pretty bad." It's down right terrible. I never even new this page existed.

Comment: Actually, there is a “Browse Questions” button in the “Public Q&A” box. Still, not very prominent…

Comment: @Holger That wasn't there when this answer was posted. This has been added later after this outcry happened. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386566/1356107 See the first image in my answer to see what is used to look like.

Comment: Most importantly, the potential customers for Teams etc are the existing users, not some anonymous passer-by who happen to step into the main page by accident. I could personally take the decision to use the services offered for the company I work for and pay up lots of cash for it, right here, right now. But since I'm a longterm member of I would never even consider that. Besides SO being a rapidly dying product - imagine the badwill my company would suffer if the SO community found out that we are financially supporting SO the company's inane changes to the site. It would be very bad PR.

Comment: @Lundin seems like the target audience for teams is fundamentally long term users of the site who like and are familiar with its mechanics and then go to their manager or purchasing department and advocate for getting it, and because they're devs and most decent employers give devs the tools they can use for increased productivity, they'll then buy it. I'm not sure if anyone actually buys teams due to a pitch on the start site, but I'm not in SE's marketing team and can't know for sure.

Comment: @Magisch It does seem as if SE's marketing team has never used the site and doesn't have a clue about the product they are selling. If implemented correctly, you wouldn't even need to market Teams because it would sell itself to the millions of existing customers. The problem is that SO has alienated those millions of potential customers, to the point where they will receive a middle finger instead of millions of dollars, if prompting them to buy anything.

Comment: @Lundin I'd probably disagree with that. They alienated a few thousand contributors at best, the vast majority of *users* does not read meta and does not care beyond finding their solution to the problem they're currently working on. I think they have a blog post coming about how consensus on meta isn't actually consensus and resetting expectations about that, too. It's disheartening yes but lets not pretend we represent anything but a vast minority of users here.

Comment: @Magisch It is still a few thousand potential business cases, each with some 10-20 potential client licenses on average.

Comment: no contest on that, and it was probably a disproportionate number of people who'd have otherwise considered buying a team

Comment: Almost Full Ack to this answer, with the sole exception of _Therefore it should be in your best interest to put that best foot forward even from a sales perspective_: If the company wants to sell the SO Teams/Enterprise Collaboration Tool, today's site reputation might suffice for bootstrapping while the relevant future reputation and testimonials will come from the corporate clients and their cordoned-off realms. In that scenario, the sales division's prime interest would probably not be the public site.

Answer (score 338):

I just landed there by accident in incognito mode, and I was totally confused and blindsided.

I do not remember a meta discussion with the community if this is an okay experiment to do, I do not remember the community being polled about this anyway.

Isn't Stack Overflow for the users, by the users? Of course Stack Exchange/Overflow needs to make money, but this, a huge ad, with no *easy* way to dismiss, to go question view by default, no way to escape it that's intuitive, and only the hamburger menu or footer menu, is very bad design.

I've been a member of Stack Overflow for years, but these are the kind of steps that kind of turn you off and make you consider making your own Q & A site that doesn't pull these kind of shenanigans without consulting the community.

My first impression of Stack Overflow now is, if I were to see the front page, oh, this is an elitist site you need to pay for. Screw that, I'll post on a forum, or ask in chat rooms.

This is my reading flow when encountering this and how I interpret it.

[image: Reading flow]

1. Private Q&A.
   Oh, this one of those exclusive sites, maybe a forum, where you get to discuss stuff in private, probably need to pay for it, it says coworker, flagship, those are pricey words.
2. Jobs?
   Oh, this must be like LinkedIn. Probably only professionals and such that only elevate themselves and talk boring stuff. You probably need to pay for exposing your account or something, as you need to on those other job sites to stand a chance
3. Create an account? And next they'll ask for my credit card, right? No thanks, I'll move on to [TechNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_TechNet) or wherever.

The words free community, do not get read or interpreted. They are not part of the message that is seen in this picture. There is no option to browse the free community. There is only this forced "CREATE AN ACCOUNT" which is a huge turn off.

But say I don't give up just yet (I will have), and I scroll one segment down.

I am encountered by this image:

[image: For businesses]

1. For businesses 
   Okay. I'm an open source hobby developer. I am not a business. This site is not meant for me. I'm off, and this site is definitely not for me.
2. Hire skilled developers? 
   I'm a private person. Why do I need this? I do like to work effectively, but I don't have a team, nor money.
3. Again, I don't need to find talent! Also, expensive word, I'm reaffirmed that this site is not for me, a hobby developer, a starting developer, and a working developer. This sounds like a site for managers/recruiters.
4. Advertising platform? What do I need that for?
5. Private? Who will answer my questions? What... how do I get to the idea of questions?... So far I've seen nothing about asking and getting a question answered.

Okay.... maybe it's like AVG free. You just need to scroll down to get the free option.

[image: Ca-ching]

No free option? Need to pay? 14 day trial? Why do I need private questions? I don't need customer support. I only want to ***ask a question how to find the foo in the bar***! *Sips tea angrily*

Okay... I just need to find an ask question button. My patience is reaching infinity, and my curiosity is morbidly big.

[image: Talent and ads]

Talent? Ads? Didn't I dismiss those just now as not relevant? Why am I seeing this. I just want to find *foo*! I'm a developer for Christ's sake, not a recruiter. What is this site anyway?

[image: Sweet diabolical relief]

1. YES! I can ask questions!!!
2. What... what.... WHAT???? Why can't I ask a question. The image changes? How do I ask a question... I need to find my *foo*!
3. ??? Create an account? But... I want to ask a question. I haven't seen any link between creating an account and asking questions. I'm more angry and confused at this time and not thinking rationally.  There is nothing for my confused and frustrated brain to link create an account with being able to ask a question.

[image: This is nice]

Well, finally something that appeals to me, a developer! Now give me a button to ask a question, I like this message. Why wasn't this at the top?

As a normal person, I see only red flags and mismatch with my needs and desires. I'm off.

Did a psychologist look at this and consider the normal user? Or only a marketing team trying to reach targets in teams and advertising sales?

You're alienating the product that makes you big. But that's okay, all companies do that eventually, giving rise to the competition that appeals to the alienated user base.

Comment: Oh, hey look. That curl question that's off topic, closed, and locked is nicely featured there. Nice that we can prominently show off topic content for advertising purposes, but can't have a useful UI.

Comment: @Dragonrage hahaha, that's hilarious, I completely missed that!

Comment: @Dragonrage heh, yea. On mobile the close reasons fill the entire screen.

Comment: @Tschallacka To be fair you can only make text so small before it gets unreadable. There's probably a lot of stuff like power user functions that aren't meant for such a tiny 'on the go' device.

Comment: This answer is delightful. I reget that I can't offer a bounty on meta.SO :/

Comment: @TylerH I don't think it's a secret that SO on mobile is more of an afterthought at the best of times.

Comment: *I do not remember a meta discussion with the community if this is an okay experiment to do, I do not remember the community being polled about this anyway* - Are you serious? That ship has sailed long ago.

Comment: +1 for extensive use of red circles

Comment: "Did a psychologist look at this and consider the normal user? Or only a marketing team trying to reach targets in teams and advertising sales?" I think we all know the answer to this one, sadly...

Comment: Best laugh I had all week taking this awesome tour to nowhere!

Answer (score 165):

I'd like to pull in a few things from the Twitter thread. I was talking about this with someone and a few other points

1. Why is this even a thing?

   Fortunately this hasn't infected the rest of the network, but this *completely* goes against a lot of the founding principles of the network. People are supposed to find what they want *fast*. The network's always been, for better or worse, designed for low friction for folks. This is... at least a small wall.

   So here's what has been done. Unless you're coming in from a search engine (*admittedly* that's a lot of people) or are logged in, you need to scroll down, find "Public Q&A" and click on it. It's basically taken discoverability for anyone logged out on the main page, torn it up, set fire to it, stomped on the ashes, then set fire to it again

   I *guess* it stops people from typing stackoverflow.com, having heard of an awesome website for coding questions from friends and finding it.
2. Why is this even a thing??

   Well, maybe, just maybe, Stack Overflow is overloaded. It's the company (well, at least the branding). It's the great big famous Q&A site. It's other products. Y'all just turned your main property into a landing page for some odd reason.

   The funny thing is no one who actually uses the site would know till they log off.

   In a sense this *slightly* feels like [misdirection](https://www.darkpatterns.org/types-of-dark-pattern/misdirection) though I'm not sure what the benefit of showing these different views to people benefits anyone.
3. Public Q&A is more than SO. SO is SO

   SO is one public Q&A site of many. I thought we were getting better about small sites being forgotten :/ . In a sense though, this kind of relegates SO (the site) to being hidden behind SO (the corporate billboard).
4. How does this even help discoverability?

   Remember [the hyphen site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange)? How they'd hide everything behind a paywall and force you to scroll down to actually find the answer you needed? Let me draw you a user story.

   I'm a new user who just found SO trying to exit Vim:

   [image: Animated screenshot showing page on how to exit from vim on SO, and what the SO landing page shows with just the URL]

   I found SO through my favourite search engine. I have a new issue. I remember the site, I type it in and...

   Erm... where do I ask a question? What's "Public Q&A?" I'm looking for SO...

   Imagine if I just got the URL from a co-worker and... well, it's confusing. We just hid our site behind a *huge* ad.
5. You could have made it easier with one simple trick

   Add a banner saying

   'Looking for Stack Overflow Q&A? Click here'

   It wouldn't even need to take up half a page
6. Sometimes the smartest people paint themselves into a corner. Maybe it's time to re-evaluate.

Ok, this is grumpy and slightly bitter. Let's consider all the lovely outcomes of that period of time we were focusing on SO, SO Careers, SO Documentation and...

Actually, it was kind of terrible. A lot of the current issues we have now are inherited from that period.

One might even call it a bit of a winter of discontent.

I mean, I get SO's trying to work out a long term, sustainable plan for making revenue. But the folks who're going to be making the decisions, and talking to their bosses are folks who're using the sites. We basically just made the site really unfriendly to new users to make it 'easier' for folks to find the paid offerings.

It feels like there's a series of somewhat unforced errors being made, with things that probably could be thought out better. This feels heavily like the single-minded focus on careers repeating itself.

In short, it's pretty terrible, and people *mainly* just want to see the questions.

Comment: You don't even need to edit the address bar. Just click on the stack overflow logo.

Comment: I hate to say it but... That felt like it had more dramatic impact....

Comment: "So here's what we've done." I didn't realize you were part of the company. I also find it slightly amusing to come in with the whole "well it doesn't effect the rest of the network" angle when Stack Overflow is the only reason the rest of the network works. If this site goes down, the whole place shuts off. No one talks about SE failing as a whole for this reason, only about if SO fails, because that is literally the only conversation which has any impact. "A lot of the current issues we have now are inherited from that period." ? What? Not really.

Comment: I'll fix the we to a you. And meh - I kinda think that a lot of the current issues, of the culture crashes and communication issues are rooted in the period that folks were focused on SO ancillary stuff. Felt a lot like there was a lack of focus on the community. As for SO is the only reason the rest of the community works? I've always felt that focus was a mistake and the network's most vibrant time was when we acknowledged the diversity of the network. Sure SO is the big site but it's not the only one.

Comment: This part would make a good TL;DR: *"It feels like there's a series of somewhat unforced errors being made, with things that probably could be thought out better. This feels heavily like the single minded focus on careers repeating itself.

In short, its pretty terrible, and people mainly just want to see the questions. "*

Comment: You need to add "Welcoming" to that list of periods of time.

Comment: Honestly? I don't have as much of a problem with that, and its *completely* irrelevant in this specific context. Its got nothing to do with the front page and trying to take on a second front at the same time weakens my point.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I disagree that including yet another failed company focus weakens your point, but your answer.

Answer (score 138):

Please remove that yellow crap:

[image: crap title]

And make this as https://stackoverflow.com:

[image: gud title]

Because 99.9999% of visitors don't need a product or business when they visit Stack Overflow and those who needs it, you know, they are probably **not complete idiots** and should be able to find it.

There is no need to make it flashing, big, animated, orange, and with a yellow background.

There is no need to double, triple, and cross-link all these ads what we have now.

Nobody will buy Teams without actually **using the site** for a while. Nobody will put here their 0 reputation profile for job without actually **using the site** first.

What you are doing is terribly wrong for users.

Comment: At least they got the color of crap right.

Comment: I think they forgot these other products are only viable because there are some people asking questions and posting answers... those are the ones who will recommend their companies to have a Private Q&A, that will tell the HR guy about this Jobs product on SO, and so on. *People won't do it just because you are advertising*.

Comment: I read that as "we less than three people who code". Yes I know it's supposed to a be a heart but c'mon, enough trying to be cute. Tweens aren't our target audience.

Comment: Maybe the "active" tab should be the first thing possible askers see when visiting this site, rather than the "newest" tab which contains a lot of bad questions that were not closed / deleted yet.

Comment: @j08691 we should all wear a "**We less than three people who code**" yellow T-shirt.

Comment: Meh, I actually think dumping new users onto a list of questions with no context is a pretty poor landing page; it's like if Google's home page was a random selection of other people's search results. So I actually approve of having a proper landing page; it just needs to put public Q&A front and centre, as the original product around which everything else is built, and which most users will want to visit first, including people who are deciding whether to buy one of the other products.

Comment: @IMSoP, not really random, but you are right, maybe "All" questions is not the best, "Featured" would be better I guess. Question: what new user expects to see when he types "stackoverflow.com" in browser address bar? ACTUALLY, copy any answer address into incognito chrome window and then click Home on the left side there or SO logo.. It's awful. As a user I want to see list of other questions to start *playing* SO, not that yellow thing I see now.

Comment: @Sinatr Don't get me wrong, I'm not defending the current marketing page. I just feel like "put it back how it was" is a reactionary comment, and doesn't account for maybe _both_ versions being bad. I think the home page should include an introduction to what the site is, links to other services, *and* prominently feature public Q&A. A dynamic set of Hot Questions could absolutely be part of that, but the first page you see doesn't need to look like search results.

Comment: @j08691 Maybe I am one of your Tweens Audience ;)

Comment: @IMSoP NO why ? Google looks the same the first time you visit and the 1000th time you visit. Your logic is flawed.

Comment: @reportgunner I'm confused. Which comment in particular are you saying "no" to?

Comment: @IMSoP I'm sorry, I just skipped to the bottom to react. I was reacting to _I actually think dumping new users onto a list of questions with no context is a pretty poor landing page_

Comment: I beg to differ, it's a great landing page - much better than one that pushes you to buy something or create an account first _in case of stackoverflow_ and _in my opinion_

Comment: @reportgunner As I said in other comments, I'm not saying _the current homepage_ is better than what was there before, only that _it's possible_ to do something better. There are more than two possible homepage designs, and "just make it how it was" is less productive than "here's how to make it good". Specifically, I think a better homepage would be one with more explanation of the site and its affiliated products _as well as_ getting you to interact straight away. I absolutely agree this should not push you to create an account straight away, or imply that you will need to spend any money.

Comment: @IMSoP that's true, I agree. But then again, when I go to google (to use your example) it does not explain to me what it is and what are their other products - it doesn't even tell me what or _how_ to write into the search box. I feel like we are on the same page though.

Answer (score 51):

What you're missing is a gigantic *Proceed to Q&A* button somewhere above the fold on the home page. Preferably just below the main headline.

[image]

Comment: It's not some kind of oversight, the design is very intentional.

Comment: Well, that's fine as long as they track abandonment. Which I'm sure they do. Time will tell.

Comment: The design looks like the typical bullshit company trying to sell their overpriced useless hype product. Note how they do not even advertise what they are doing, but place a prominent slogan "We <3 people who code" instead of e.g. at least showing a screenshot of the site. Or telling in large letters "We build a Q&A site for developers" What will come next? Blurring the answers for users that are not logged in?

Comment: Presumably they score 12 in [the Joel test](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) and thus do hallway usability testing (at a minimum).

Comment: @allo: Blurring the answers **and** truncating them to 280 char **and** serving those as JPG images with artifacts due to high compression.

Comment: @allo The slogan, at first glance, suggests that fewer than 3 coders work for SO now. Perhaps this explains the increased focus on marketing...

Comment: For only `$9.99` a month, you can view up to 100 answers and 25 comments! But consider our deal of `$49.99` a month, where you can now view up to 1000 answers and 100 comments! (Our best package deal).

Comment: @allo not to get too far off track but I have to agree, the language used to promote teams, etc. wouldn't help an engineer make a decision, plus to be honest I'm pretty sure anyone who has ever bought anything on behalf of a company before has a powerful filter in place to automatically skip past words like "empower", "enterprise", and the entirety of the "customers" section (bandwagon stuff). I always figured writing like that was targeted more at investors than customers.

Comment: @jrh I think you underestimate how a lot of purchasing decisions are made -- sales and management people will see wording like that and then demand the IT department purchases and implements it.

Comment: @TylerH "I read about this trend on <Business Magazine Name here> in an airplane for 5 minutes and we need to get more efficient so I'm going to buy this thing I googled without even consulting the people who have to use it" -- yeah I can imagine that happening I guess. Our local guys are immune to fluff for the most part but maybe somebody sufficiently high up who wanted to uh... "modernize the collaborative business process" or something like that would do that as part of a "bold vision". But they'd probably at least have to meet face to face with the service provider, FWIW.

Comment: Old-ish person here. I didn't even realize at first that this was an emoticon of sorts, I literally read "We (are) less than three people who code", which I thought was a really odd tagline for an Q&A page.

Answer (score 45):

If a new user actually manages to find the Q&A site on this new landing page, this is what they'll see in the main navigation area on Stack Overflow.

[image]

There are three Stack Overflows here and one Home. The Stack Overflow logo goes to the products page (which is the new landing page). The Home link also goes to the products page. The Stack Overflow in the Products dropdown goes to the products page as well, though only if you're already on the Q&A site, if you're on the products page it goes to the Q&A site. The Stack Overflow with the earth icon actually goes to the Stack Overflow questions page.

I'm no UX expert, but I would guess if you asked new users where they'd expect those links to go, they would probably get almost none of them right. The only way to understand how to navigate SO here seems to be trial and error.

Comment: I guess this replaces the Tour...

Comment: Especially because a globe icon sometimes means "change language".

Comment: I think the overloading of the name "Stack Overflow" is a significant part of the problem with this whole situation. There really needs to be a distinctive branding for "Stack Overflow Public Q&A" which can be consistently highlighted both on marketing pages and within the main site. There also needs to be consistent binding of labels to actions, rather than the word "Home" meaning something completely different to logged-in and logged-out users.

Answer (score 43):

My company does not allow us to log in to websites (security measures). For that I use Stack Overflow as private mode and phone. About the new look of the home page, I guess this is the new policy of Stack Overflow, and I don't have any comment about this.

I just want to suggest that if it is possible to create a new button in the top bar beside *Products*, *Customers*, and *Use cases*, we can access the questions quickly, please.

For example, like this:

[image]

Comment: Agreed - SO *is* programming questions and their answers. People who land here looking for questions or answers are *not* gonna find them easily. Maybe that's actually a really good thing and will turn off the spigot of bad/low quality questions? I don't know. But design 101 says 'make your product discoverable' and right now the meat & potatoes of SO is not discoverable on that new landing page.

Comment: That seems like a very strange policy that would make it harder to get things done.

Comment: @JoeW Isn't the purpose of a company policy to make your job harder?

Comment: With how it's placed and aligned, the "Questions" button here might be interpreted as "questions for our products", like an FAQ section?

Answer (score 27):

It's been mentioned in comments, but I don't think in another answer, so I want to bring it out in bold letters:

**The best advert for the paid services is the public Q&A.**

I totally understand wanting a better landing page that shows off the different products; in the long term, it could actually reduce the need for spammy self-advertising on the rest of the site. But right now, the focus of this page is entirely wrong; the public Q&A is not just one product among many, it's the hub that everything else is built around.

- Most of the people landing on the home page are looking for public Q&A. You want them to see the other products as they pass, carry on, and come back later to learn more, not turn away to another site.
- Showing off the free and open Q&A community demonstrates the attitude of the company, and builds trust.
- Anyone evaluating Private Q&A is going to want to see how the platform works before buying. Public Q&A gives them an opportunity to do that.
- Similarly, anyone interested in Careers, or other advertising opportunities, wants to see what they're buying into.
- The people using public Q&A may well be *influencers* not *decision-makers* when it comes to the other products. Enlist them as your sales assistants!
- Your strongest advocates will be *established* users. Why hide this page from them?
- The Stack Overflow brand is built on public Q&A; you want to say "we also do this" not "we now do this instead".

So, some concrete suggestions:

- Start the page with a "welcome to Stack Overflow" that talks about how great the public Q&A site is, and lets people jump straight in. Replace the yellow box, which any startup could claim, with a message that actually *means* something.
- Make the home page the same for logged in and logged out users, but make sure the current logged-in homepage is easily accessible too. Maybe make the landing page the target of the header logo, and replace "Home" in the sidebar with a different label.
- Include some dynamic content on the home page; a set of "Hot" or "Featured" questions, or perhaps just tags. Something to lure the user deeper into the site, without being as overwhelming as the old homepage.

Answer (score 20):

On the one hand, you have SO actively attacking veterans with the "Welcoming" philosophy and changes. On the other, they've now replaced the home page with one that provides no apparent avenue for *asking* questions even after the link change. About the only way they could make it look more like they don't want any users is to shut down the site. The kind of PR this generates is only going to make the situation worse.

Answer (score 15):

Metrics! Metrics!! Metrics!!!

If the new home page is unwelcoming, shouldn't it show up  in the metrics?

I agree it's seems bad to me, but I'd love to see by just how much.

Comment: I estimate that it is 1.32 unwelcoming.

Comment: ... with a margin of error of plus or minus 3 percentage points at the 95% confidence interval :)

Comment: @Berriel If the margin of error is that big, we really need a larger sample size ;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Is that a percentage? Or is the site really 132% unwelcoming?

Comment: @JL2210 it's a score.

Answer (score 12):

For general example only.

Imagine What if **[GOOGLE](https://www.google.com/)** does like this? - Marketing its most popular products on the home page like put products blocks, tell users what company does, remove that **Search Text Input field** and put a button (anywhere in Hamburger menu or in other menu) which tells **Click to Search**. All users will be frustrated.

As far as I know, the main purpose for Google is to provide a SEARCH ENGINE to everyone. They have had that **Search Text Input field** since they started. User wants to search something. User opens web browser and opens Google website. User types in that Search Text Input field whatever they want to search, gets results and fulfills their purpose.

Later on they have different products like YouTube, Play Store and many more. But they still didn't change that **Search Text Input field** (their main purpose) and put all other products in top right corner in Products tab.

Did Google change their Home Page Search Text Input field? - NO

We all know [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is one of the great sites for anyone that codes. But as previously, user comes to Stack Overflow site, they should be able to see [All Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions).

But if we want to go with new design then provide at least *Button Link* like **Browse Questions** (directly on rendering the [primary above-the-fold content](https://web.dev/first-meaningful-paint/) without scroll or clicking anywhere) which they already have BUT now we have to scroll down or click on **For Developers** or on **Products** or on **Hamburger Menu**.

All users (New ones and old ones) will eventually find it out how to get to the questions page, but my point is users should get to the questions page with minimum clicks and without scrolling, if we can't put all questions on home page as before.

Answer (score -20):

Perhaps put a "take a tour" button by the "create an account" button?

[image]

Answer (score -38):

As someone who has never asked or answered a question on Stack Overflow, I never got a good idea of what's expected of a question, even after looking at so many for work...

As someone that has talked with a few long-time users of Stack Overflow about troubles with a huge amount of incoming questions and not enough people to properly moderate them... **I kind of actually like this.** All the essentials are still there (log in, sign up, search bar), and it may actually send a better message than the page of active questions.

I jotted down [a quick thought in The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=7719012#7719012) a while back:

> What I remember from being new... I read a lot of posts. But a site can have a frontpage full of bad questions, but you don't really see it until they're actually closed. (If no one comments, you may see downvotes on stuff that seems totally reasonable and you won't find out why it's bad until it's closed).. so you see a lot of broken windows

It's especially true for visiting the home page of Stack Overflow. You get dropped into this huge wave of new questions and activity, and as a new user you might not be likely to ever see one closed or downvoted enough to make you think twice. Instead, the constant stream of questions sends a message of 'okay, time to drop one like that too!!'.

Right now, there's this big giant search bar at the top, instead of a flood of activity. [That new user that remembers Stack Overflow from a previous visit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386505/new-home-page-makes-it-seem-like-so-doesnt-allow-free-use-any-more/386521#386521). They can use the giant search bar. The more experienced user that accidentally got logged out? They can find the log in button exactly where it always was.

The user coming in through a search engine won't see this page at all before they get to their answer. That person that got told about this awesome site with questions and answers? Well, hopefully they got told to use the search function too!

Someone that's already moderate familiar with other parts of the network? They should know about the existence of the search bar already.

And from what I remember, you won't be able to ask a question without having at least an unregistered account. So the sign-up button is also still there, for those who are in a hurry. I think there will be only a very, very small amount of people that will be confused here, thinking Stack Overflow is suddenly behind a paywall.

So, this makes me wonder... what do people without accounts/logged out need with a list of active questions, most of them [broken windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) anyway? If you're logged in, you can use it to help moderate or find interesting stuff to answer, but if you're logged in then you won't see the page. If you've visited Stack Overflow before and had a tiny bit of experience here getting your answers, you know where the search bar is or to log in before you can ask/answer anything.

**Instead of adding some kind of banner or big 'Go to Public Q&A' button that drops new users into the big chaos that's Stack Overflow, tweak the search bar a bit to make clear the one that seeks shall still find free answers (hopefully).** And I'm kind of curious to see if Stack Overflow is collecting data on this, if the amount of bad questions by first time users will go down or the amount of searches up, or something...

Comment: I agree that "here's a bunch of random low-quality questions" is not a great landing page, but you haven't mentioned anything *better* about this new homepage; it might as well be lorem ipsum. If the aim is to persuade people to use the search function, there should be a great big search box right in the middle of the page. If the aim is to welcome people to the public site, the public content should be more than just a passing mention hidden among the business services.

Comment: @IMSoP the 'better' thing for me is that I don't see the chaos of random low quality questions anymore. I already mentioned tweaking the search bar, putting it on a more prominent part of the page might be part of that too. I'm not denying no change is needed there, just that I for one am glad to be rid of the chaos! :)

Comment: That's funny, because we suggested when they were redesigning the homepage years back to copy the good thing quora (or something) has that is basically a search bar.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell That's why I said "might as well be lorem ipsum". As far as you're concerned, this page is now blank, a less distracting way of reaching the search bar; but if that's the requirement *it's a terrible implementation*, because there's still a whole lot of text for you to ignore. That doesn't just require "tweaking the search bar", it requires a fundamental rethink of what belongs on this page.

Comment: @Braiam I guess not Quora, or it's changed since then, because [their home page](https://www.quora.com/) just asks me to sign in, without even telling me what I'm signing in to!

Comment: I hadn't seen this change from the perspective of crap questions encouraging more crap questions.  It's definitely a good thing to hide that away.  I'm not sure that positive outweighs the marketing slant it's gone to now, though.

Comment: Huh... Interesting angle. My initial reaction was "this won't matter - almost no one who isn't already logged in asks or answers from the homepage" - but that ignored folks who *use the homepage to log in*. Gonna chew on this for a while, thanks. Love the idea to emphasize search btw.

Comment: Thank you for adding a productive counter to this discussion. While I concur with the thought that seeing a bunch of broken windows is bad, I think there are other solutions for that. I also agree with the comment that you haven't told us what would be better or why the current page is better. In my mind, what's up now is far worse because I can't even tell there are questions and answers I can access for free without creating an account. I absolutely abhor sites that make you create an account before you even know whether you want to use the site.

Comment: Do people use the search bar? I tend to use Google. For the fun of it I searched for ".net register delegates with IServiceCollection" on the site. The result was a single question with no answers. I did the same search on Google and got tons of results, including useful answers on SO. What's up with that?

Comment: Yeah, they should make search work properly before expecting anyone to try to use that.

Comment: This is a very interesting take, but I doubt it was the thing that SO marketing department was thinking about.

Comment: @ScottHannen I use the search bar almost every day. However, if I'm trying to find a specific question, I usually go to google and add `site:stackoverflow.com` at the end. The search bar is bad for that, and the 'duplicate question finder' is somehow *worse*.

Comment: @Shog9 I thought about as much that rarely anyone will likely just visit `stackoverflow.com` randomly. Then I visited a question as a new user, like about 10k people per second do from Google, and I instinctively clicked the big logo to get to the home page...and got to this weird sales page, too. Maybe it's still my training from *being* a user that makes me click the big logo to get to the questions list, but when I saw that happening I quite changed my mind about the practical impact of this thing.

Comment: @user1118321 Re: Thank you for adding a productive counter to this discussion. ... "I absolutely abhor sites that make you create an account before you even know whether you want to use the site." The last line is literally what sub-standard or garbage sites are all about (phishing, lot of ads website, bad-design, etc) which make it not trustworthy and make you doubt "is this really the right site for me?" As an alternative, they could've returned the old design which displays s what this sites about and put another page like [More Feature] which display the current weird design.

Comment: Hi @Tinkeringbell, personally, I have only one problem with your comment to IMSoP and your answer that I think no one has highlighted at this point, but you're inactive in SO overall. How can you say that you see low QA answers if you don't answer any question or ask questions? It's like I'd say that X beer is bad when I don't drink at all. I can see your activeness in IS, MSE, etc. But you have only the newcomer points inherited from your other networks in all SO sites. I'd first start asking and answering some questions in our network and then, let's talk about QA.

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete It's based on two things: `As someone that has talked with a few long-time users of Stack Overflow about troubles with a huge amount of incoming questions...` as mentioned in the post I regularly hear other people say it... And don't answer or ask doesn't mean I have never used SO before, or visited the front page of SO before, and seen the amazing level of active questions there, realizing some of them are low quality by just looking at them from an 'I know SE sites' perspective. I think I only mentioned low quality *questions* with regards to that, I certainly meant to.

Comment: I'll happily admit I have no sense of 'low quality *answers*' on SO, and I think my post never makes any claims with regards to those. I do know that I sometimes find answers that don't work on my machine though...

Comment: There is one more problem with emphasizing the current search bar - its search quality is very low compared to Google - cf. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357462/why-does-google-return-better-search-results-for-stack-overflow-than-stack-over . In the few cases I have forgotten this and used the in-site search by mistake I was usually unable to find what I was looking for and had to use Google anyway.