# Why has the SO homepage been replaced with a marketing page?

Tags: discussion, homepage

When I attempted to use SO from the [homepage](https://stackoverflow.com) this morning I was confronted with this rambling marketing page rather than the usual questions page.

[image: SO Marketing]

In fact, it wasn't at all clear how to actually get to the questions, or see what the SO experience is. Why has this change been made and isn't it counter-productive to introduce this friction to the experience?

Comment: Related [Faster access to questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386495/7666442) & [New home page makes it seem like SO doesn't allow free use any more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386505/7666442)

Comment: This is really really horrible. To me it looks like SO begs for money, in a pity way. Huge disappointment, SO is not what it used to be, and in a very bad way. :/

Comment: We love people who code. But people who ask questions - not so much.