# Create new URL for new Stack Overflow company / business products and services homepage

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, homepage

The [new Stack Overflow homepage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386540/3345375), which describes all the company's products, is worthy of its own sparkling brand new URL:

### https://stackoverflowproducts.com

---

[image]

---

Then https://stackoverflow.com can direct to "Questions," as before, and everyone is happy.

Comment: https://stackoverflowbusiness.com/ exists, but I guess that wasn't enough. :(

Comment: Define "everyone".  Are you talking about us, those who are authenticated into Stack Overflow, or those who haven't authenticated before to Stack Overflow, or whomever wanted this to be shown as part of the home page for the unauthenticated users?   A decision was made to do this, and while we may not *like* or *agree* with the decision and we can certainly ask for it to be changed, be careful with such powerful universal quantifiers.

Comment: @JeremyBanks SO has multiple categories of products now: some for business, and some for developers. "Stack Overflow Products" covers everything.

Comment: @Makoto "Everyone" includes (1) people who want the new page design and (2) people who want stackoverflow.com to show "Questions" for all users, as it always has up till now. I suppose I was exaggerating for effect when I said *everyone*, which doesn't include (3) those who want to strongly de-emphasize Q&A in favor of other offerings; because if that was the motive for the company's decision, then concealing the "Questions" page makes sense.

Comment: I'd say that right now we're in a unique position.  [We've got an opportunity to give feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386505/1079354) on the fact that the home page turned into... ***that***...and it's important not to squander it by giving into the temptation to be hyperbolic.  Don't assume motive or population; just give *your* feedback on it and that's all that needs to be done. :)

Comment: Yes, good point. And on the page you linked to, many people posted feedback that I agree with so I'll make sure to upvote their posts.

Comment: eh, I like the idea of having a landing page at https://stackoverflow.com, i just wish it were about Stackoverflow rather than all of the side products. An alternative url would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Perhaps instead a test should be done to see where people navigate to from stackoverflow.com. Do they go to questions, sign up, login or view one of the products?

Comment: @tas And which of those outcomes would be 'right' ?

Comment: `status-declined` - Thought as much. The value is in the original URL.

Comment: If you typically use SO without logging in, bookmark this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Active

Comment: @TamásSengel Usually, if I'm using SO without logging in, it's because I'm using a computer where I can't store a session. Those tend to be the same machines where I can't save bookmarks either unfortunately.