# No chance given for a new question after 6 months question ban

Tags: support, post-ban

From [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans):

> **Does the ban last forever?**
>
> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

My last question has been asked on 1st October 2018.
So by what I understand from the text, I should be given a new chance on 1st April 2019. But, today is 3rd of July 2019 and the new chance isn't given to me.

So what could be the reason?

Comment: No question you asked and deleted in the meantime?

Comment: @BDL I was unable to ask, but that question which was the reason for the question ban was deleted by other user's votes.

Comment: When has that deleted question been asked?

Comment: @BDL Because the question is deleted by other user's vote, I don't have it in my question list to see the right date (not also in deleted questions list), but I think it was about 10/11 months ago.

Comment: It would be great if the error message said when the question ban expires, but I guess the technology isn't there yet...

Comment: Guess we have to wait for a mod to pop by and show us, but this has been asked many times on meta, and every time there's a forgotten deleted question.

Comment: strongly related: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/165773). Instead of [polluting SO homepage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386505/839601) with spammy trash they would better implement this. Or, at the very least do a small config change allowing users to check their deleted posts for 6 month instead of current 60 days. Why do we have to host requests like this at meta and load moderators with checks that could be instead done by banned users

Comment: @Stijn the q-ban doesn't expire, it simply is there based on the algorithm. The allow once every 6 months is part of that algorithm. It is not given you have to wait 6 months if your posts have been voted on in the mean time. I give you it could include in the error message when the last question asked was.

Comment: Apparently you don't remember [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54037969) from January 4th…

Comment: @deceze And to think this question wouldn't have been asked if they waited 1 more day...

Comment: looking at that Jan, 4th question, please use the advice in [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [There appears to have been no effort to debug the code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: @deceze You're right, I had forgotten that one.

Comment: @Erik is a witch! How could he have possibly known that? Burn the witch!

Answer (score 4):

The Help Center is correct. Even when you are [question-banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), you get one free chance to ask a question every six months.

This is not a bug. It has not yet been six months since your last question. You asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54037969/check-if-all-the-characters-of-two-strings-are-common) on January 4, 2019, and deleted it on May 20, 2019.

The system has a longer memory than you or I.

For tips on working yourself out of the question ban, please see [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). Spoiler alert: it boils down to improving your existing questions to raise your overall quality score. The score includes both deleted and non-deleted questions.