# Clicking on Stack Overflow Logo must redirect to questions page (when browsing as a new user)

Tags: feature-request, homepage

It kinda feels different that clicking on the "Stack Overflow Logo" redirects to the same intro page again and again. Can this please be modified to redirect to the questions page once the home page is visited? It must be a bit hard for new users to find the link to the questions page.

[image: redirection GIF]

Comment: I agree; at the very least it should not be clickable on the page it redirects to, otherwise it should redirect to the questions page from the homepage; maybe vice versa from the questions page (back to the home page?)

Comment: @TylerH Why redirect to marketing page from the questions? Lol

Comment: This is also annoying even after you've found the questions page, as even there both the Home link and the SO logo link to the marketing page again.

Comment: Finding the question page be like: https://imgur.com/n4mrIz6.gif

Comment: @BlackThunder Well, it is the *home page* whether you like its content or not.

Comment: But it's not as easy to find a purchase path on the questions page also "Products" doesn't get highlighted on the question page.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386505/6296561