# The Stack Overflow site for anonymous users is confusing

Tags: feature-request, homepage, anonymous-user

There have been rather substantial changes to the SO homepage visible for anonymous users that are not logged in or don't have an SO account. The biggest change is certainly replacing the Q&A homepage with a landing page for Stack Overflow products, but that issue already has a meta discussion and I won't rehash this here. But this change and others have in total made the anonymous version of SO far more confusing in my opinion.

I'm assuming a new user here that does not know yet what exactly Stack Overflow is. I also assume they managed to find the questions page from the landing page.

The information about SO they can see on the landing page is that it's about developers, that there is Q&A and it's about sharing information, or something like that. But then they land on the questions page, and there is nothing else that explains how SO actually works.

The Tour is entirely absent and not linked at all on the main page as far as I can tell. The help center is well hidden, there is a link but it's among 20 others in the footer, and unlikely to be found by a new user.

This is unlike how other SE sites look for anonymous users, on every other site you can still see the help icon in the top bar, as well as the site switcher.

While hiding the help is my biggest issue, the whole thing is exacerbated by the new landing page that focuses on products, not Q&A. This already makes it more complicated to understand what exactly SO is. These changes along with the sidebar changes also made navigation rather confusing (see [my meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386651/347857) about how there are now several links named Stack Overflow on the page that all do different things).

It's also confusing that the home link and the logo link back to the landing page even when you're already on the Q&A page. This isn't the behaviour I'd expect, and I'm not sure how users are supposed to figure out that they have to click on the lower Stack Overflow link with the globe in front to get back to the Q&A page.

I can't really believe that these changes are positive for the new user experience, the new page feels disjointed and confusing.