# Change the SO homepage: Make it clear this is a programmer Q&A site

Tags: discussion, status-declined, stack-exchange, homepage

An un-logged-in user visiting stackoverflow.com. This is what they see:

[image]

I have all sorts of reservations about this page, but many of them are a matter of taste, or are debatable (maybe) - this post is not about all of those, especially since the homepage is not just now being introduced in this form. There's just one point that's really bothering me:

**A (non-logged-in) person visiting this page will likely not realize that "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers."**

While the statement that Stack Overflow "loves people who code" is intended to make people feel welcome - neither this statement, nor the graphics, nor the subtitle, suggest what people are welcome *to*. . It takes at least two clicks in - selecting one button out of two, then one box out of three - before the public Q&A aspect of SO takes center stage. (Either that or a search in the top bar - but the user would not know what that search bar is for and will be unlikely to use it.)

For contrast, consider the StackOverflow.com Tour page - from where the quote above is taken. It presently looks like this:

[image]

I'm not saying that should be the site front page. But when you look at it, you know what goes on in SO.com, without you having to scratch your head.

Now, I realize the community doesn't control what appears on the site's main page, so this post is intended to:

- Bring this up for discussion among MSO readers.
- Appeal to SE Inc. to consider making changes to the homepage to address this issue. (Note I didn't say "replace" or "redesign"; it could be a significant change or a minor one.)

Comment: The ship has sailed...

Comment: @SamuelLiew: How do you mean? That is, I realize the page is what it is now and not what it once was, but that doesn't mean it can't be improved. I didn't say what changes. Even changing the wording of the subtitle could be a marked improvement

Comment: The pointyhairs running SO have gone all in on trying to sell paid services to make their vulture capital happy and are counting on 99% of new visitors coming here via google links pointing to specific questions.

Comment: @DanisFiddlingbyFirelight: To the extent of wanting to hide the public site from non-registered visitors? In the hope they might be duped into paying for something?

Comment: @einpoklum to users trying to research what SO is, a home page filled with bright and colorful, positive messaging is far more likely to make someone want to spend money than landing on a home page full of garbage questions.

Comment: "For developers, by developers" seems to indicate that the site is for developers/programmers...?

Comment: What else does "people who code" mean, except programmers?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386505/new-home-page-makes-it-seem-like-so-doesnt-allow-free-use-any-more

Comment: I mean hey, [I tried](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344052/175248).  I don't think they're going to budge.

Comment: I don't feel like the existing text, *Stack Overflow is an open community for anyone that codes. We help you get answers to your toughest coding questions...* is unclear.

Comment: Sometimes it gets confused with a travel site by non-developer users like my sister.

Comment: that's a mighty... odd flight trajectory, with the loops and such

Comment: @BSMP: 1. That text is at the bottom of the landing page (when you're at its top). 2. It's sub-optimal, but it's certainly better than "we build products that empower developers". Actually, it _contradicts_ the earlier sentence.

Comment: @KevinB Copy/paste code from SO into your flight module and guess what happens!

Comment: 'A (non-logged-in) person visiting this page will likely not realize that "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers." ' I fully agree, but I also wonder though why still so many people register new every month. Why are they doing it and what are they expecting from the site?

Comment: @Trilarion: 1. Do they really? How many? 2. Maybe they're coming in through search engine results.

Comment: Sure. More than ever register. Currently about 170k per month. See for example: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1186795#graph and note that also even more are not seen anymore and and increasing part of these don't [engage meaningfully](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344836/how-does-se-inc-understand-and-define-meaningful-user-engagement) with the site according to the company. The homepage features this nice signup button and for whatever reason, because it really isn't conveyed clearly what the site is about, people seem to sign up.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. While nearly every programmer knows what Stack Overflow’s core product is, most are unaware of our Teams or Jobs products. This page is intended to showcase all of Stack Overflow’s product offerings. I’ve passed along the feedback to our marketing team to consider emphasizing Public Q&A however I’m setting this as [status-declined] for now as there are no immediate plans to make changes.

Comment: @Des:  That kind of feedback is way, way too important to be buried in a comment.  It should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @Makoto sure thing, I can do that.

Comment: @Trilarion: I guess people just want to feel loved, then?

Comment: Coders at least. Not sure if they also love people who don't code.  ;)

Comment: @Trilarion: Where are those days where they could say "We love people who write good answers to questions about code, and the rest of you scum we will tolerate barely"?

Comment: @einpoklum: [Like the Vogon captain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiYd4-9aNyI&t=5m24s)?

Answer (score 51):

I threw a ***massive*** fit about this some time back, after I had been inadvertently logged out and noticed the change that had been made to the home page—even going so far as to make compelling logical arguments—because **hiding free public Q&A (or otherwise obscuring the fact that we provide this, and no paywall exists) is a *huge*, unacceptable watershed to me**.

Alas, nobody who cared remains employed by Stack Exchange, either on the community team or in management. This is evidently what they want the page to look like, and they see nothing wrong with the unmistakeable messages that it sends.

I wholeheartedly endorse your feature request, and share all of these concerns, but lack the energy or motivation to repeat my prior arguments here. If anyone with the ability to change things cares, you know where to find me.

Comment: About the same thing happened to me. But - note I'm not trying to tell them to drop the silly graphics or rhetoric or ASCII-heart. Or not to push their commercial products. My request is very modest.

Answer (score -11):

Thanks for this feedback. While nearly every programmer knows what Stack Overflow’s core product is, most are unaware of our Teams or Jobs products. This page is intended to showcase all of Stack Overflow’s product offerings. I’ve passed along the feedback to our marketing team to consider emphasizing Public Q&A however I’m setting this as [status-declined] for now as there are no immediate plans to make changes.

Comment: While nearly every programmer knows what Stack Overflow’s core product is" <- If you restrict yourself to those people who got to the SO front page without an account, that is likely not really the case, because once people get to know the site they either have an account or go in through search engine links. But - passing this on to the marketing team is better than nothing, so... not downvoting. Also, please ask them to at least include a sentence to the effect of what I quoted.

Comment: You could put the motto under the "Public Q&A" button if anything.

Answer (score -58):

Stack Overflow is one of the top websites in the world. Not knowing SO is a website for Q&A for programmers is like not knowing Google is a search engine or Amazon is a book selling place.

Anyone who still struggles to understand what SO is probably don't need it.

Comment: I wonder what the marketing teams over on Google and Amazon think of this answer ;)

Comment: To me amazon isn't a book selling place, it's an everything selling place, and yet if I want books I'll go to a bookstore

Comment: If Google's homepage said "we love people who are looking for stuff", and didn't have an obvious search bar in the middle, I don't think they would fare as well.

Comment: @einpoklum: that bare page with just a box to *type in what you are looking for* was astoundingly unique in its time. All other search engines looked, well, much like the SO homepage looks *now*.

Comment: Yet I continue to run into people whose opinion of SO is "I asked a question about using X and it got closed. I'll never go back."  It never registered with them that SO was only for programming questions.