# Do discussions in Meta ever change anything?

Tags: discussion, meta

As a fairly casual user of SO, it seems like my sidebar frequently links to vigorous discussions on Meta related to potentially changing aspects of how the site works. Yet, it feels to me like the site has changed little over the last decade.

I'm wondering if my feeling is correct. If I was to travel a decade back in time and open SO, what would I see re. functionality, look and feel compared to today? If there are significant changes, can they be traced back to discussions in Meta?

Comment: Well the rules for what's on topic have changed drastically. I'm pretty sure the initial trial of only needing three close votes instead of 5 was also prompted by discussion (and of course the full rollout later on).

Comment: only rarest, with support of many user you could prop ably change something's for the better, but as you notice you get plenty of downvotes here in an instant, so you must have a very good point and bring direct in your question very good arguments that people and mods can get behind

Comment: Reasonable question, predictable voting. Just a comment: There may be significant changes that cannot be traced back to discussions in Meta with certainty but might still be inspired by them. Meta is so big with thousands and thousands of feature requests that it's somewhat probable that any possible change has already been discussed in this or a similar form at some point.

Comment: Hm, this question was apparently controversial. Insight from down- and close voters would be appreciated. Thank you CodyGray and @Makoto.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do discussions on Meta change *major* aspects of the site's operation? Rarely. It does happen sometimes, but even then, only within certain limits. There are fundamental principles of how these sites operate that are not and have never really been open to change. This is why the site seems to have changed little over time. You don't mess with what works—and Q&A works.

Do discussions on Meta change *minor* aspects of the site's operation? All the time! Minor changes have been made to the site's user interface; new features/tools have been added; verbiage has been tweaked in the Help Center; requirements/guidelines have been expanded, revised, and clarified; privileges have been added; badges have been added/removed; and many more things.

And then there are a zillion other things that moderators have the power to change by themselves (without involving Stack Exchange staff members), such as closing/reopening questions, locking/unlocking posts, editing locked posts, modifying the tagging system, changing our policies and/or the way we handle things (e.g., rules enforcement, flag handling, user suspension, etc.), and so on. These have all been changed and/or evolved in response to Meta discussions *many times*, and continue to do so. Moderators pay close attention to what goes on on Meta, and even if we don't immediately take action as a result, we do take community feedback into account, both to inform/adapt our own actions and when discussing internally with staff members as your community-elected representatives.

Related reading: [What weight do Meta discussions have?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325924/what-weight-do-meta-discussions-have)

Answer (score 13):

...Yes and no.

A lot of the conversations that have happened on Stack Overflow itself have largely been geared towards the kind of content that the community sees as on-topic, as well as improvements to moderation tools, and so forth.  The visible changes resulted in, for a brief period of time, [a different definition of "too broad"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291819/175248).  The mighty dupehammer was also borne out of discussion here as well, as well as [reducing the close vote count to 3 instead of 5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348560/1079354).

However, I would strongly argue that, [in spite of constructive community feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384380/1079354), there are just [some things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386505/1079354) that [will not change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396254/1079354).

Supposing that you wanted to actually engage with the site and have some impact on what changed around here...maybe 2 years ago I'd have said that diving right into Meta would've been fine, but I don't know right now.  They're working their own roadmap right now and sure, we're a part of that to some degree, but I don't see Meta having that same level of feedback or input that we enjoyed some time ago which *did* enable a lot of those changes.

Comment: "reducing the close vote count to 3 instead of 5" It was discussed for many years but the decision to do it was only made after the company decided to make an experiment and then decided after seeing the results and Meta feedback. Not sure how much that should count. Maybe the company would have gotten to the same conclusion at around the same time even without Meta ever existing, or maybe it wouldn't.

Comment: It came about because certain of us, having read that Meta feedback (and/or having provided it ourselves), hounded certain staff members whom we felt would be receptive to these demands *incessantly*, until we finally either convinced them or they obliged us merely to shut us up. I'd say that it is a success story of Meta. About the only argument against it is that the moderators in favor of it probably would have reached that conclusion without a Meta site, but I don't think we would have had the ability to articulate our reasons nearly as well. @Trilarion