# Technical Communities Recently Active Questions with questions without answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Atm there's a new div. It's indeed a great effort to start connecting the silos.

[image: Technical Communities Recently Active Questions]

To me, would be more interesting if in that list only showed up questions that don't have yet any answer or, worst case scenario, without any marked as correct answer as that's more within my interest within the community - to answer questions. Reading the «Technical Communities Recently Active Questions» atm feels like wasting time.

I might not be the only one with the same problem, but don't have numbers to provide.

Comment: Given that the majority of users search on SO for answers and not answerable questions, defaulting to unanswered questions doesn't really make sense. If you want that, add `answers:0` to your search.

Comment: @BDL I'm not searching them in particular, they just show up in this new div that was introduced.

Comment: [It's an experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396370/215552). That's all. As noted on that question, "We would prefer general questions about the experiment to be asked on [the MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346137/technical-site-integration-observational-experiment-live-on-stack-overflow) (as the general experiment extends beyond Stack Overflow). If you would like to report bugs and issues, please feel free to do so [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396370/215552)."

Comment: It would really be easier if you invest a bit more time in your posts and use a understandable terminology. When your first sentence goes off about a "search bar" but you are talking about a question list, it's really hard to understand what you mean. As for the list and bug reports for the A/B testing: See Heretic Monkeys comment.

Comment: Yup, my bad on that BDL. Fixed it to div. Thank you for that @HereticMonkey. I assumed because that change was only visible in SO that it should be done here. Noted for next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would not be possible to do in a good way. You'd end up with low quality questions the vast majority of the time. The only reason the system knows which ones to present as 'interesting' is because of the number of answers and views a question has.