# How is this comment not rude or condescending?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, meta, specific-comment

I flagged this comment as rude or condescending:

> I usually have my ad-blocker disabled on SO, but this made me activate it again and create a rule to hide that stupidity.

Personally I wouldn't have been offended but I thought this isn't necessarily the kind of discourse we want to encourage or promote.

It's been declined. Fine by me but why? Was I right to flag it or am I just being precious here?

Comment: To whom was it being rude or condescending?

Comment: I assume to comment was posted on meta, at which point..... meta is a funny place

Comment: @HereticMonkey That comment was posted on meta; I don't want to create unnecessary troubles by giving names. Perhaps a site moderator could look into my flags history and tell me why.

Comment: I was thinking I remembered this comment, and it was talking about the new Technical Communities feature. The "stupidity" in question in that case was on Stack Overflow's part -- some moderators are marginally less likely to censor speaking out against the company.

Comment: yeah, i mean, it could have been said in a nicer way, but meh, in context it's not as bad as it looks reading it without context here. This on a question on SO would be incredibly insulting, as it'd be critiquing someone's question or answer, they're work. In this case, it's critiquing a new feature. Quite a bit different.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I sort of see your point but wouldn't that encourage people into thinking they can allow themselves to be rude when responding to staff? The user could have said the same thing in a nicer way IMHO ;)

Comment: @customcommander I agree with you, but since this is [Meta comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396370/technical-site-integration-observational-experiment-live-on-stack-overflow?cb=1#comment765245_396370) I don't think the same rules apply. However this looks like a conversational comment that doesn't add anything to the post.

Comment: Personally, "rude" and "condescending" are a higher bar than "could have been said in a nicer way".

Comment: Generally i feel that Staff members have the tools to deal with cases like this if they deem it necessary. They're the perfect ones to decide whether or not they think something pointed at them or something they built is rude.

Comment: `Personally, "rude" and "condescending" are a higher bar than "could have been said in a nicer way".`

Fair ;) But also "Could you have said that in a nicer way perhaps?" is a polite way of saying "Could you have been less rude about it?" :D

Point taken nonetheless.

Comment: Remember that comment flags aren't escalated to the user who posted the comment. They're not a "please consider rephrasing to something nicer" flag. They are shown to moderators, where our only option is to delete the comment (thus validating the flag) or decline the flag (thus preserving the comment). In this case, as I often do on Meta, where the comment is not irredeemably rude, I will choose to preserve it. I sometimes even edit comments to remove abusive language in an attempt to preserve as much of value as possible. But most mods won't go that far.

Comment: @CodyGray If you don't delete the rudeness then you are enabling the rudeness. Other content is irrelevant. You are saying that it's OK to be rude if you say something useful. That is very bad.

Answer (score 16):

I declined your flag on that comment.

I didn't consider the comment to be problematic since it did not attack any specific individual and especially since it was posted on Meta. I submit it should be acceptable to call an *idea* stupid, as long as you are not calling a *person* stupid. (That said, there are almost always better, more eloquent ways of expressing your dislike of an idea.)

Note that having a comment flag declined doesn't mean that you did anything wrong. It doesn't mean that you were wrong to flag it. It just means that the moderator who handled your flag disagreed with you and felt that the comment did not need to be deleted.

Comment: -100 for not enough eloquent words :)

Comment: Why is it okay to call an idea stupid (apparently an idea of a staff member), but calling a question stupid isn’t? Cf. CoC _“No name-calling or personal attacks. — Focus on the content, not the person. This includes terms that feel personal even when they’re applied to content (e.g. ‘lazy’).”_ Is this fine on Meta?

Comment: Calling the idea stupid is calling the people who are promoting it stupid. What calling something stupid means is that it is the product of a stupid person.

Comment: No, it absolutely isn't. Our identity is not defined by our ideas. I have loads of stupid ideas. I appreciate when folks call them out as stupid or wrong. It isn't offensive.

Comment: What you don't consider offensive could be interpreted as such by others. Could it be possible that the CoC that @user4642212 mentioned also makes provision for that? I don't mind your handling of my flag that's fine, but user4642212 made a good point too.

Comment: @customcommander The problem that with "What you don't consider offensive could be interpreted as such by others." is that what is the limit of what can be determined offensive or not?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte Of course. The CoC sort of provides some guidelines though. The word stupidity was unequivocally directed to the content but feel personal (although YMMV). The example in the CoC is relevant to this case IMHO but I'm happy with the decision regardless.