# Cannot open a question using the keyboard interface and the Enter key

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, question-lists, keyboard-shortcuts

Until now, I have been able to quickly open the first question on a question-listing page (such as the start page or the page of a tag) by pressing <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. <kbd>J</kbd> has selected the first question on the page and <kbd>Enter</kbd> has navigated to the currently selected question.

However, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key no longer opens the question for me.

Does this only happen to me? I'm using Firefox 97 (64-bit) on Windows 7.

Comment: Also reported by [Gilles](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/375555/289905).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alas this unfortunately was caused by a regression during [site redesigns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el/375555#375555) wherein a number of keyboard shortcuts lost their anchors, but fear not as this is now fixed and you can `Enter` away into questions again! ⌨!

Comment: Hum, still doesn't work completely "smoothly", on 'Main' (`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/[tag]?tab=active&page=1&pagesize=30`), `j` and `k` first open the Quick Search upon a fresh (re-)load and don't do any Scrolling, only work after waiting for the Quick Search to disappear, same also after an `Enter` +  `Back` (`Backspace` Key does nothing btw, have to use the Mouse). // `j` and `k` work better on 'Meta', but same "Difficulty" after an `Enter` + `Back`, then they also open the Quick Search first. // `FF105, Win10`

Comment: @chivracq Admittedly our keyboard shortcuts haven't seen a _ton_ of 1st class attention over the years - they've remained largely intact from [launch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site). To my knowledge, the `Backspace` key was never intended to have any particular functionality. I know some browsers used to support this hence things like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/go-back-with-backspace/eekailopagacbcdloonjhbiecobagjci?hl=en), but otherwise this seems like it could be better fit for a `feature-request`?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm also having trouble reproducing the lack of scrolling/"smooth" functionality you mentioned on the link you posted - would be great if you could perhaps post a separate `bug` to help warrant a further investigation.

Comment: Well, I had done a bit of Testing for this Thread a few weeks ago and had been able to reproduce OP's Issue with `Enter` (on FF[101-103]), but didn't notice "anything strange" at that time with `j` + `k`. (`Backspace` was not "working" already indeed.) // But don't "worry", if OP is "happy" with the Fix, that's "good enough for me", I don't really use Shortcuts myself, (I find `j` & `k` not "*logical*" anyway), I prefer to keep a (pinned) Tab on all Views/Tags I monitor ('Main' + 'Meta'), and open any newly active Thread in a new Tab (with `Middle-Mouse` Button).

Comment: Regarding the emoji in this answer: see [For a more considered use of emojis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386228/for-a-more-considered-use-of-emojis) (prompted by [this post by a (now former) staff member](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386178/data-science-time-june-2019-and-the-tumbleweed-badge).