# Updated button styling for vote arrows: A/B testing has concluded

Tags: discussion, voting, user-interface, a-b-testing

**This experiment has concluded**. We've gathered and analyzed the results in [Results of the voting arrow experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420698/results-of-the-voting-arrow-experiment).

---

This week, we're rolling out a test to update the appearance of voting arrows for both questions and answers, which will bring some accessibility gains, namely affordance, feedback, and meeting [WCAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Content_Accessibility_Guidelines) compliance; it also maintains aesthetic cohesiveness between services, by bringing them in line with the voting displays on Teams and articles within Collectives. To be clear, this does not include comment voting arrows, nor does this update include any changes to the mechanisms in voting.

First, the up and downvote buttons are getting fancy new coats. Wrapping the vote buttons in an outline like this makes them look more actionable, which is an environmental clue for users, especially new ones. (These are buttons, come press them!) This should make them easier to use and more obvious, which should lead to more engagement with them.

[image: Image showing the new vote arrows]

We're also updating how the arrows look after a user has voted. The older arrow contrast change upon voting does not meet WCAG accessibility contrast tests. Along with updating the color for compliance, we're also adding clearer feedback for vote status. You'll see contrasting colors for up and downvotes. This offers more clear and visibly distinct feedback upon voting.

[image: Image showing the new vote arrows with an upvote cast]

Comment: Since this is an A/B test – what is being tested/compared between the groups? How much people vote?

Comment: Is this the final design that testers will get to see? In my opinion the buttons need to be more spaced out or a little bit smaller. Right now, the vote count looks rather squished between those big circles.

Comment: @QBrute id assume the final design testers will see is the one presented on collective articles currently, if you wanted to look at a live example

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "This should make them easier to use and more obvious, which should lead to more engagement with them." I guess the success metric is votes per visit.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, the vote buttons are being tested. The screenshots above will be displayed in the test group and we will be comparing vote events between test/control. Ideally, there is no regression so if the vote events are flat between both test and control we will consider that a success.

Comment: @QBrute That's correct - this is the design that users bucketed into the test group will see. We expect that this experiment should take about two weeks to run. Thank you for the feedback, we'll revisit this when we have results of the experiment to share with Meta.

Comment: @notarobot to improve "accessibility" and adhere to "guidelines"

Comment: thanks so much! as a colorblind user I really appreciate the changes and attention to all visual impairments :)

Comment: One remark: the score seems a bit too small to me. It's quite smaller than the buttons. It'd be nice if the number was slightly larger than what's shown in those screenshots IMHO.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli In fact it is an actionable element (for a lot of people at least) which through this change now looks even less so. This change is a step in the right direction, but let's not pretend that this is the end station.

Comment: @Gimby yeah I feel like we are taking away too much of the (IMHO very needed) emphasis on post scores, e.g. with the last questions page layout update which basically made the score almost invisible.

Comment: What will the dark mode and high contrast mode look like?

Comment: Bucketing seasoned users into the test group seems a waste of time; they already know how to vote and vote often. I'd strongly suggest targeting new users

Comment: While I'm not a fan of the new look of the UI itself (to the point where I dug this post out just to see what happened to my buttons), the accessibility benefits seem obvious, and I'm all for that. I look forward to seeing the results! Hopefully those will be shared here (or elsewhere?) too!

Comment: I think making clickable items look more obvious is long-overdue so I'm all for that - I do however dislike this look, it just doesn't fit with the rest of the site - nowhere else are there circular buttons, SO is pretty much rectangular throughout, the top menu button highlight in a rectangle, the ask question button is rectangular... the voting buttons should be smaller and rectangular and the accept answer checkmark desperately needs to look clickable also.

Comment: *`...it also maintains aesthetic cohesiveness between services'* seems to just mean you made a change to your paid service and now need to bring all of the other sites inline with that. I agree with improving accessibility, but this seems a weak attempt. While possibly more button-like, the thin stroke and smaller up/down arrows offer less visual contrast on the page while also reading poorly agains the body of the question/answer.

Comment: Is there any means to request removal from the test group?

Comment: There never is, @Phil, so I very much doubt there is or will be here. It likely wouldn't do any good, either. You'll eventually need a userscript to revert back to the old styles, once this is pushed out (and it likely will be, since the A/B test is only attempting to measure whether there is any major breakage, not whether it's actually a positive change), so you might as well just set about getting that userscript/userstyle in place now.

Comment: _"not whether it's actually a positive change"_: how can that be of use?

Comment: What's the percentage of users targeted by this WCAG compliance push? Not sure whether I'm one of them (a 100% functional ADHD coltorblind), but this change makes SO nearly unusable for me. Distracting as hell tbh. The A/B test should be designed very carefuly to estimate engagement and disengagement metrics.

Comment: Giving visual clues is a great concept. I hope something like that is done for the "Ask Question" button as an important alternative to the "PUSH THIS ONLY BUTTON Post Your Answer", which is too often misused for commenting, for asking, .... Maybe the queue of posts who need to be flagged as NAA can then get shorter.

Comment: This new "feature" is ugly but frankly I'm not surprised, since it seems every change you do is for the worst. Why don't you do something more creative if you are looking to increase voting? E.g. when a user who has enough reputation to vote is browsing a question, show him a short-lived pop-up that encourages to vote. You could do this for users who have asked a question and haven't voted on answers, too. A pop-up would be very effective.

Comment: elevator buttons?

Comment: Why circle buttons then? And what about the accept button? I would first remove that ugly `border-radius: 1000px;` which would fit with the rest of the UI much better. And since we're at it, I have never been a fan of that orange color once the button has been actioned. Orange has a *warning / caution* connotation for me (even though people will disagree with that statement). I would either use green for up, red for down, or blue for both.

Comment: I wonder if it has been taken into consideration that such an A/B test could probably show more user clicking the new buttons just out of pure curiosity for the new design.

Comment: Please apply the style using proper specificity instead of relying on crutches like !important. That makes it much harder for us to make our own styles to override them.

Comment: I appreciate it being an A/B test rather than an immediate change, this is a step in the right direction. I really hope you'll consider user reaction when deciding if the A/B test was successful or not.

Comment: Was this kind of edit seriously required?

Comment: This post should've shown the new voting buttons alongside an example question/answer. How the buttons look in isolation is not very useful. I saw this change *because* this design looks out of sync from the rest of UI. Also, were any other design options considered?

Comment: @TylerH you can always use a bigger hammer and repeat the class multiple times: `.cls.cls { foo: baz !important; }` overrides `.cls { foo: bar !important; }`

Comment: If you really do care about accessibility, why hasn't the keyboard interface [you accidentally broke four months ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416033/cannot-open-a-question-using-the-keyboard-interface-and-the-enter-key) been fixed?

Comment: There is not a single element on SO that has the color black. Except the vote arrows. [rude comment removed –mod]

Comment: Please just [Revert back to the old Upvote-Downvote buttons' design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418916/revert-back-to-the-old-upvote-downvote-buttons-design). 53 people, including me don't agree with this already. This may shoo away new users. It is also very uncomfortable, and every time I see the new buttons, I feel like `Ctrl+W`-ing and playing [chess](https://www.chess.com/play/online/doubles-bughouse) or Minecraft.

Comment: Could you please give us some way to choose which style we want? I'm currently stuck with the new style and I prefer the old one. https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/15578194 doesn't have anything related to the style of the vote buttons.

Comment: With new buttons this post definetly would gain more downvotes.

Comment: As usual, an over-emphasis on "equity" leads to making things worse for almost everyone.

Comment: How do you decide when to show the new design? Because I can see the old design on my work chrome profile, and the new design on my personal profile.

Comment: Let's all agree that old buttons were much better and this does not help in any way, shape, or form. Does not look too appealing anyways. Build Better.

Comment: TO THE STACKOVERFLOW CREATORS: If it helps several users like @MichaelDelgado but an immense amount of others dislike it and get distracted from the actual use of the site, why not give us a simple optional switch in the settings? That way everybody's happy. but make everybody know about the setting of course, through a message similar to the 'welcome back'.

Comment: Also you apparently forgot deleted questions. See https://imgur.com/WGK6BtQ — Top rounded button touches the border of the deleted question red section. Ugly.

Comment: "To be clear, this does not include comment voting arrows" How does this square with the idea that this change is important for accessibility? Will there be a future change there, because otherwise it just comes across like accessibility is just being used as an easy pretext to avoid design critiques rather than a legitimate concern on SO's part

Comment: Will a mouse-over colour change be implemented, which is a visual usability cue?

Comment: Could someone at Stack Overflow please fix the accessibility problems with this design in dark mode and high contrast?

Comment: I can see that the grey on white is now discouraged for lack of contrast.  So colouring them black solves it.  But a circle around them is the wrong way to go.  It adds to clutter and distraction and helps no one.  If you are really worried about lack of contrast (as you should be).   All the other info in grey should also be coloured black.  But please do not add more lines.  Look at the guidelines again, the trend is to remove unnecessary lines as they cause the eye to stray.

Comment: The other option is, which will please everyone is to have setup option in the profile to use high-contrast mode or not.  To reiterate, red is wrong, circle is wrong.  For most people, the current scheme is perfect with the least amount of distraction.  So why stuff  it up for everyone.  Just allow a high-contrast mode which gives the new design.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Can you explain how it's a benefit? Is it the circles themselves that make it easier to find the voting? Are you using a screenreader and there's some CSS or similar that's better with this design? If it's limited to colorblindness, what's the specific advantage? That the selected arrow, up or down, is much more distinctly selected now? How does that help your day-to-day (aka What use case does this change unlock?)? Mostly just curious, as I have some input on my employer's websites, eg. ;)

Comment: Is the A/B test over? Or was I somehow moved to the group that sees the old design...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I can still see the new buttons. Have you moved to a new location? I have been booted from a B group before when I used SO from a different location. The A/B split seems to not be related to account or machine, exactly. So far, I've been on the same group when using SO from two different machines at home. But I visited my parents during in the middle of an earlier test and went from B to A.

Comment: @VLAZ Yep, I'm in a different location, but a few days have passed before the design changed for me. Interesting.

Comment: It's in StackOverflow now and I hate it.  It should have been a setup option !!!  If it was really about contrast, then a whole heap of other things should have been changed.  Now the focus is on the arrows, instead of the score.  How is this better for anyone ????

Comment: Just wondering... How are SE designers going to center a 18x10 px arrow within a 45x45 px circle?

Comment: A whole lot of people seem to  independently of each other associate these with elevator buttons. The digit between them would be your current floor. Hmm.

Comment: I agree with most of comments which say the new voting arrows are too large and/or don't fit with the rest of the design. I don't feel that saying they don't fit is subjective. They simply don't match the rest of the design elements. Maybe the entire UI should be updated; I don't know. As I think back to my graphic design professors or mentors I shudder to think of what their comments would have been regarding such an out of place element. Let's just say it was the '90s and no one wore kid gloves during design critiques, lol.

Comment: I was torn between upvoting this post because of the attempts to meet contrast requirements, and downvoting it because it looked bad. **Until** I realized, in reading various [answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418954/16775594) and [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-currently-in-a-b-testing?cb=1#comment916102_418888), that it actually _doesn't_ meet WCAG requirements. Guess I'll downvote yet **another** "site improvement" meta post :-(.

Comment: So... it's been almost two weeks and this post has a vote ratio of -76% (275 down, 86 up) and 16 answers, none positive. Is that _"enough data"_?

Comment: @Phil Not sure that meta has such a strong weight with the company. If you read this post carefully you realize they have set their mind on the feature already and will only scrap it if it receives a significantly worse reception on the site. Don't want to say that the score here isn't a strong negative signal but the company often listened more to the main site users (or maybe Twitter) only, so don't keep your hopes up.

Comment: I will never get used to these new upvote buttons

Comment: So is this thing staying?!

Comment: I think it is not beautiful and very big for page

Comment: Been over two weeks now and plenty of hate (-77% vote ratio). Time for it to go? Otherwise, can we get an update on the data collected?

Comment: Yep, they've realized that if they *don't* post things to meta, then we get mad. But if they post things to meta and then walk away immediately after, we get slightly less mad.

Comment: I have intentionally avoided voting on anything while these buttons are used. They are seriously hideous, and distracting. I'm all for accessibility, but please also consider _design_.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Or they are just too busy to react here in time and answer to every comment of every user. Maybe they are still collecting data or discussing the collected data and how to factor in the meta feedback. Remember there is no obligation for the company to come back to meta or to follow the feedback given here. We just need to be patient, I guess (we've done our part).

Comment: @Phil We will be pausing the experiment this week and will be analyzing results to share with the community before determining next steps.

Comment: @Trilarion I was referring to more instances than just this one, but you have a good point. I'll delete my comment, because on looking back, it's more than a little unreasonably resentful. However, I think (and this has been said before many times my many others) that what _really_ bugs me is that we get these meta posts announcing something the community didn't get to approve. There's absolutely nothing wrong with updating the vote arrows, but what _didn't_ happen was asking for the community's opinion _before_ coming up with a design. Hence the design was one that the community didn't like.

Comment: @Trilarion If the question had been more along the lines of "We're planning on updating the vote arrows for better accessibility, here are the standards we need to meet, how do y'all think they should be styled so that they look good but still meet those standards?" I think it would have been much better received, because it would have shown that the community, not the webpages, was foremost in the company's mind.

Comment: This seems like a classic case of change for the sake of change

Comment: -267 downvotes!?? never seen such a thing

Comment: @user18807217 Oh, you ain't seen _nothin'_: [Sunsetting Jobs and Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293/16775594) Check out [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416084/16775594) to it, too.

Comment: Wow, I'm mighty pleased (even if temporarily) to see the old style voting buttons back. Can UI changes be rolled out with a toggle in the user's profile? So we can either opt-in or opt-out?

Comment: @CodyGray _"the A/B test is only attempting to measure whether there is any major breakage, not whether it's actually a positive change"_ At least you guys are honest this time about not caring, I guess.

Comment: No offence to any challenged users, but one ought to think what point does pleasing 1% of users outweigh mild irritation to 99% users? This might be beneficial to challenged users, don't really understand how, but forcing non-challenged users to take it or leave it is not the best way to go. SO could very easily have made a accessible version and left it to the users to decide if they wanted to use the accessible version. In a way they could make vast changes beneficial to special people without making it less pleasant for most  of its users

Comment: @MMM Cody is not involved with either preparing or conducting the A/B test. Same applies for all the elected moderators. They aren't involved with the development of the platform - that's done by Stack Exchange. Whether Cody (or any other mods) care or not is not really a factor. What Cody Gray was saying is descriptive based on the past Stack Exchange release practice. Not an explanation of what the plan is from an insider perspective.

Comment: @VLAZ ah, fair enough, sorry for sounding accusatory Cody!

Comment: @tanj92 "We will be pausing the experiment this week and will be analyzing results to share with the community before determining next steps." Just curious. What is the conclusion from the experiment and what will the next steps be?

Comment: @Trilarion We're still compiling the results of the experiment and will be doing a bit more analysis into vote events. We also know that there have been several bug reports submitted so we will be regrouping to review and prioritize. We will communicate to Meta in a separate post the results and next steps. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @tanj92 Just out of interest: how is the compiling of the results going? Any next steps?

Comment: @Trilarion thanks for following up. This has been long overdue and I apologize for the delay. The short answer is that we will not be graduating this particular experiment. We will revisit this as part of another upcoming initiative and think about this in a more holistic way and working with Meta as early as possible. Thank you for your continued patience.

Comment: @tanj92 Thanks for the response. Btw. did the change in the style of the voting buttons change engagement significantly in either direction? That was one of the hopes initially as can be seen above.

Comment: @Trilarion with approx. 2.5 weeks of experiment data that our Product Analyst looked at, we saw a lift to overall votes in the experiment group, but when further segmenting by upvotes vs downvotes, there was slightly more downvotes (as well as upvotes).

Comment: @tanj92 That doesn't sound so bad. People probably didn't downvote more because they didn't like the new style, rather the new style made them aware of the vote buttons more so that they voted more and more voting might be seen as good, even if the average piece to vote on may get a bit more downvotes than upvotes compared to outstanding pieces. Apart from the criticism about the style this isn't all bad news.

Comment: I'm sorry, I logged in to SO one day and saw the new design. The first thing I thought was "ugly". It's too big, inflated, and... weird. Besides that, I still think clicking the old vote buttons are quite intuitive; this design is implemented in enough sites that if you're computer-proficient enough to even visit SO you should know that.

Comment: A simple question: is there an option to turn this off? Where is it located?

Comment: It seems I only ever come to Meta when there's some change I don't like with the design of sites on the network. I came to see what the reaction is, and once again, it seems as though this change is generally disliked.

Answer (score 429):

While the new Upvote/Downvote button design is a nice attempt at a new style:

- it's too big
- it detracts from the actual answer post
- it doesn't fit in with the rest of the post design
- it makes an otherwise great and long-lasting layout design feel cluttered.

[image: Old vs New Voting Buttons]

---

Compare the whole layout of an answer post with the "new" buttons VS the old buttons:

> **NEW**
>
> > [image: Why new voting buttons are a step down]
>
> ---
>
> ### ------ VS ------
>
> ---
>
> **OLD**
>
> > [image: Old voting buttons blend in more naturally]

[Slider Comparison](https://imgsli.com/MTEzOTA0)

---

Looking at this, the old buttons also look a tad too big. Here are some alternate suggestions I quickly whipped up:

[image: Alternative design suggestions]

The only positive outcome of this redesign is that there's now a clear separation between the "sidebar" (with the voting buttons) and the main post area -- the two "columns" appear more nicely. With the old buttons, the distinction is a bit blurry and everything seems a bit "floaty".

But I mean, who asked for this?

Comment: Personally speaking, I just loved the simplicity of the big and clear-shaped old voting buttons, and the "power" I've come to associate with them. The new ones look super generic, like in another other website, and detract way too much from the actual answer. The only look good on button down state (when vote has been cast), but in idle state they look horrible :/

Comment: Sorry, forgot that I was using a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revert-stackexchange-form/fliedkodjpgomjmjbkaehhlllnhmcjnh) to revert Stackoverflow CSS changes to the old ones. The new buttons might be fitting in after all, but I've not been a fan of all the recent changes, which is why I've been reverting those changes. Didn't realize this, so my opinion may not be valid :X

Comment: Got to say, I agree that this change is basically useless and also seems very out of place compared to the rest of the UI.

Comment: *"it's too big"*: Yes, it *appears* bigger than any other element on a page, including the headline (at least at some zoom levels). [Sample page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69492656/how-to-test-library-fragment-with-espresso-without-activity).

Comment: It's amazing how the new buttons manage to be both too big and too small at the same time. They occupy a lot of real estate: too big. The actual outline is, what, one pixel wide? Too small. The first time they popped up, I was lost. I could barely see the outline of the buttons. Both the inner color and the outside are the same, or too similar. I had to switch to the high contrast theme in order to be able to see the new fugly buttons in the first place.

Comment: @Sam Yeah, and the arrows also look too small...

Comment: I ABSOLUTELY AGREE: REVERT IT! It seems to distract a lot of users. I also don't know if anyone ever seriously had problems with the previous design.

Comment: @Prid We’ll re-consider the size of the buttons and make changes iteratively if needed, but right now are not immediately changing it. We also have to keep accessibility and usability in mind when thinking about it.

Comment: You're using the same shade of gray of the old design, which doesn't pass WCAG.

Comment: @Prid To somewhat echo your sentiments, I find the original SO arrows to be the most iconic and recognizable part of the site/brand (even more than the logo). They are one of the best designed UI elements I have ever had the pleasure of using, and changing them (to me) is akin to overhauling the logo or brand color scheme. (although worse because unlike the logo, I need to look at the score+buttons multiple times every time I navigate a page).  Needless to say I vote keep the orginals.

Comment: I have the same impression that this feels out of place with the rest of the UI. I tried to get used to it but every time I have gone to SO in the last few days, it has felt slightly jarring to look at the new vote button circles; they appear unfinished and ugly to me personally. I enjoyed clicking the old buttons and they didn't distract me from reading the content of the post. The new buttons distract me and I feel less inclined to want to vote on SO with this change, so please include an option to turn this off if you decide to keep the change(or maybe make it part of the high contrast UI?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts's_law indicates that slightly larger buttons are much easier/efficient to interact with.  This will also benefit users with fine motor challenges.  I think shrinking the buttons to be smaller than they currently are would be a step back for usability from this standpoint.

Comment: I prefer the aesthetics of the one we already have, but you should consider how the new style might make it easier with people with any visual difficulty. UI design takes a lot of things into account.

Comment: I'm used to grey signifying a _disabled_ state; so, these buttons make more sense to me. That said, the design is still rife with interactive elements which don't look like they're available. ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: @canon: good point, but more important is ***consistency***. If a website has one button design, it's pretty easy to learn its function and expect similar buttons to have same function. But with this "new" button design, you get a mix of different button designs, like you said, and that creates confusion and uncertainty, which leads to more friction and users having to re-learn the website's interactive behavior.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by, _"still rife with interactive elements which don't look like they're available."_ The change (while better) is inconsistent with the unintuitive way they've designed everything else.

Comment: Just noticed that the buttons with the new styling turn the triangles gray when the post is *locked* (and thus the vote buttons are non-interactive). [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM4oU.png); [link to an actual locked post for demonstration purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) (for those lucky victims of the A/B test)

Comment: @CodyGray: ironically that looks better and should've been the default color for interactive state ^^; but this will only add to the confusion...

Comment: To be honest, I was on stackoverflow because of the old buttons..

Comment: agree to all you say

Comment: The only reason I enter stackoverflow meta is when I find out my UI suddenly changes. I get the need for accessibility, but it's very ugly ☹️

Comment: @LuckyLukeSkywalker Re: "REVERT IT!": same here. Is there an option to revert it?

Comment: What the -- did the so design team change it back and forth now or what? Why not only show it for those who have it selected or those having certain accessibility browser settings on? Aren't there any media queries for this?

Answer (score 129):

Is the tick icon planned to be changed to a button (for the asker only, and Admins in Teams) too? If not, then I feel like this would conflict with this statement:

> Wrapping the vote buttons in an outline like this makes them look more actionable, which is an environmental clue for users, especially new ones. (These are buttons, come press them!) This should make them easier to use and more obvious, which should lead to more engagement with them.

If the vote arrows are now vote *buttons* then the tick icon will look *less* actionable if it isn't a button too, in my opinion.

Without Accept as a Button (which any who wasn't the asker would see regardless of a change):
[image: Unvoted and not accepted not as button][image: Upvoted and Accepted not as Button]

With Accept as a Button (which only the asker (and Admin?) would see):
[image: Unvoted and not accepted as button]
[image: Upvoted and Accepted as Button]

<sup>*Please excuse the awful image skills and any saturation differences.</sup>

Comment: (as a note, these changes are already live on Teams and so I'm pretty sure the answer is "No" - there's no circle around the check mark on Teams)

Comment: Thanks, @Catija , I just checked on my teams account and you are correct, [the tick isn't a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/livEC.png). It would, however, be nice if it were.

Comment: It's only a button for the asker, though, right? :)

Comment: True, it *should* only be a button for the asker (and perhaps an admin in Teams, as shown in that picture). I should make that clear. :)

Comment: I say just get rid of the tick icon

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for providing the screenshots and the feedback around the accept tick icon. We'll revisit this after with the product design team once we've collected enough experiment data and we will share with Meta.

Comment: Thanks, @tanj92 . It might be interesting to monitor is accept rates differ. Though it's not really a KPI users (like myself) should care about, it would be interesting to see if users that do get the buttons and are the asker accept less. I can see it being a little confusing for user whom are new to the platform more than those than aren't.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. We can monitor that as a secondary KPI metric. We track accepted answers internally so this should be doable.

Comment: Oh God, please no, that would only make the "new" buttons feel even more cluttered with yet *another* circle... as if the new buttons weren't already detracting from the actual answer, this would steal even more attention from the main info :(

Comment: Considering that only the asker would see the tick as a button, I'm not sure I can side with you on that it would steal attention; the asker *should* be interested in the answers as that's why they asked the question, @Prid . That that isn't the point of the answer here; it's to denote that the inconsistency more, and that it'll make the accept icon look less actionable when the goal is for things to look *more* actionable. I don't think we have any chance of stopping the permanent change to the vote icons/buttons.

Comment: @Larnu: Sorry, my mistake! Hastily jumped to conclusions, but thanks for clarifying still -- your points make sense :)

Comment: In addition, if you're going to make things look actionable, once the user has the privilege to see the vote split, the vote count should be made to look like a button, too. And I agree with others: Circular buttons look out of place on this site. Make them rectangular or, if you must, rounded rectangular with small corner radii.

Answer (score 86):

> Wrapping the vote buttons in an outline like this makes them look more actionable, which is an environmental clue for users, especially new ones. (These are buttons, come press them!) This should make them easier to use and more obvious, which should lead to more engagement with them.

You say you want the vote buttons to **look like buttons** to provide a recognizable environmental clue for users? Well, then please consider the following modest proposal (interactive demo in the code snippet below):

```js
const imgUpNot = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6r0J.png';
const imgUpHot = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/7joO5.png';
const imgUpHov = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/TicRh.png';
const imgDnNot = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZXuh.png';
const imgDnHot = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sZHq.png';
const imgDnHov = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/1voqE.png';

$('.js-vote-up-btn')
  .click(function() {
    const el = $('img.iconArrowUpLg');
    const other = $('img.iconArrowDownLg');
    const score = $('.js-vote-count');
    score.text(parseInt(score.text()) + (el.attr('src') === imgUpHot ? -1 : (1 + (other.attr('src') === imgDnHot))));
    el.attr('src', (el.attr('src') === imgUpHot) ? imgUpNot : imgUpHot);

    $('img.iconArrowDownLg').attr('src', imgDnNot);
  })
  .mouseover(function() {
    const el = $('img.iconArrowUpLg');
    el.attr('src', (el.attr('src') === imgUpHot) ? imgUpHot : imgUpHov);
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    const el = $('img.iconArrowUpLg');
    el.attr('src', (el.attr('src') === imgUpHot) ? imgUpHot : imgUpNot);
  });

$('.js-vote-down-btn')
  .click(function() {
    const el = $('img.iconArrowDownLg');
    const other = $('img.iconArrowUpLg');
    const score = $('.js-vote-count');
    score.text(parseInt(score.text()) + (el.attr('src') === imgDnHot ? 1 : (-1 - (other.attr('src') === imgUpHot))));
    el.attr('src', (el.attr('src') === imgDnHot) ? imgDnNot : imgDnHot);

    $('img.iconArrowUpLg').attr('src', imgUpNot);
  })
  .mouseover(function() {
    const el = $('img.iconArrowDownLg');
    el.attr('src', (el.attr('src') === imgDnHot) ? imgDnHot : imgDnHov);
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    const el = $('img.iconArrowDownLg');
    el.attr('src', (el.attr('src') === imgDnHot) ? imgDnHot : imgDnNot);
  });
```

```css
body, #content, #answers, .answer
{
   margin:  0    !important;
   padding: 0    !important;
   border:  none !important;
}
```

```html
<html itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/QAPage" class="html__responsive html__unpinned-leftnav" lang="en">

<body class="question-page unified-theme js-comments-menu-events">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/Content/Js/third-party/npm/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/js/stacks.min.js?v=6cc27826a5fd"></script>
  <script src="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/Content/Js/stub.en.js?v=e700279bb0cc"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/Content/Shared/stacks.css?v=3bbf3c79def9">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/Content/Sites/stackoverflowmeta/primary.css?v=205802c9d683">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="content">
      <div>
        <div class="inner-content clearfix">
          <div id="mainbar" role="main" aria-label="question and answers">
            <div id="answers">
              <div class="answer js-answer accepted-answer js-accepted-answer">
                <div class="post-layout">
                  <div class="votecell post-layout--left">
                    <div class="js-voting-container d-flex jc-center fd-column ai-stretch gs4 fc-black-200">
                      <button class="js-vote-up-btn flex--item s-btn s-btn__unset c-pointer " data-controller="s-tooltip" data-s-tooltip-placement="right" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Up vote" data-selected-classes="fc-theme-primary" data-unselected-classes="" aria-describedby=""
                        title="This answer is useful">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6r0J.png" class="svg-icon iconArrowUpLg" width="45" height="45">
        </button>
                      <div class="js-vote-count flex--item d-flex fd-column ai-center fc-black-500 fs-title c-pointer" itemprop="upvoteCount" data-value="24" role="button" tabindex="0" data-s-tooltip-placement="right" data-controller="null s-tooltip" aria-describedby="" title="View upvote and downvote totals.">
                        42
                      </div>
                      <button class="js-vote-down-btn flex--item s-btn s-btn__unset c-pointer " data-controller="s-tooltip" data-s-tooltip-placement="right" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Down vote" data-selected-classes="fc-theme-primary" data-unselected-classes="" aria-describedby=""
                        title="This answer is not useful">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZXuh.png" class="svg-icon iconArrowDownLg" width="45" height="45">
        </button>
                      <div class="js-accepted-answer-indicator flex--item fc-green-500 py6 mtn8" data-s-tooltip-placement="right" tabindex="0" role="note" aria-label="Accepted" data-controller="null s-tooltip" aria-describedby="" title="The question owner accepted this as the best answer 17 hours ago.">
                        <div class="ta-center">
                          <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconCheckmarkLg" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36"><path d="m6 14 8 8L30 6v8L14 30l-8-8v-8Z"></path></svg>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh man... this makes me miss all the beautiful custom up/down vote arrows on different StackExchange sites :'(

Comment: Am I allowed to click the up-arrow button in your snippet *and* the up-arrow (not a) button on the post itself? Or would that be considered voting fraud?

Comment: Well, this is just fantastic.

Comment: Looks like vote breakdown has stopped working for me? Should I report this as a bug? :-D

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine No, this is open-source, so you can fix it yourself! :-)

Answer (score 82):

The styling for a focused non-checked button is a little ambiguous on dark mode compared to light mode:

| Dark mode | Light mode |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Focused upvote button on dark mode] | [image: Focused upvote button on light mode] |

The fill color is pretty noticeable on dark mode, which might lead some users to mistakenly think that the button is checked. This can happen by selecting the button using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key or by clicking the button to *undo* the vote:

| Not clicked | First click | Second click |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Upvote button not focused] | [image: Upvote button focused and checked] | [image: Upvote button focused and unchecked] |

Answer (score 65):

As many others have stated, the design doesn't really match the site.
I would propose removing the `border-radius: 1000px;` and changing the `padding: .8em;` to a `.6em`, so it doesn't take up too much space.

Here is a preview of what that would look like.

[image]

Comment: Not bad, but they look like badges now :) I think we just need to go full ham and use thumbs instead of triangles. There ain't no misunderstanding the symbolism behind the thumbs up or thumbs down. Except the origin of it.

Comment: wow, nice buttons, I want it added

Comment: square buttons look hideous here

Answer (score 61):

What will the HTML look like? Will it be easily revertible with custom CSS?

<s>While I fully understand this change and applaud SO for making the site accessible,</s> I'm probably not the only one who prefers the classic look.

I have since changed my opinion and now consider this to be just another attempt of pushing some random change onto users. The large majority of users will have no benefit from this change and there are plenty more important things on SE that can be made accessible. The vote arrows aren't one of them.

Comment: While we do not provide any support for using third party extensions, you should still be able to modify the CSS to revert back to the current styling.

Comment: @tanj92 do you think you could possible use fewer `!important` declarations in CSS? They should be a last-resort

Comment: Unfortunately because the up and down vote buttons are done via SVG, it will require JavaScript to truly fix. While you can reset the path values in SVG using CSS (e.g. `button.js-vote-down-btn svg.iconArrowDown path { d: path('M2 11h32L18 27 2 11Z') !important; }` for the downvote arrow, the viewbox attribute on the SVG parent container of the vote buttons will need to be reset from `0 0 18 18` to `0 0 36 36` to fix (and height and width attrs will need to be set to `36`, too). And CSS cannot affect HTML or SVG attribute information; JavaScript is required to do that.

Comment: (CC @tanj92 regarding my previous comment)

Comment: @MMM I just published a user script here https://stackapps.com/questions/9443/revert-stack-overflows-new-up-down-vote-buttons that reverts the buttons back to something very close to what they were before.

Comment: @TylerH I just used a `scale` transform to fix the icon size. Seems to work, at least visually

Comment: While this change may make the site more accessible for _some_ people, I feel like it makes it _less_ accessible for _lots_ of other.

Answer (score 58):

Maybe it's just me, but my brain doesn't easily recognize the "it's up-voted" part.
Now it takes effort. (not good)

[image]

So, please either:

1. revert it
2. allow us to choose
3. or modify your change to make it intuitive/pleasant

(Pretty sure, 1. and 2. are the safest options.)

Comment: I struggle with this issue everywhere where there are only 2 options and one of them is differently colored than the other, and there's no immediate and intuitive way of telling which one is in "active" state and which one is in "dormant" state. Good catch! The new colors look better, but your proposed way is definitely easier to grasp :)

Comment: true, didn't even see that. Btw: who even makes these decisions on so/se ? has there been a poll besides this thread?

Comment: I fail to see what is better about the old version? How is the new one not clearly upvoted?

Comment: @CrisLuengo For me, the new one looks like a focused-but-not-clicked highlight

Comment: @Izkata The only reason you don't say that about the old one is because you have been looking at those for 11+ years. You're used to the old thing and don't like change. This is understandable, but not a good argument, if the new thing indeed improves accessibility as they claim.

Answer (score 54):

I have to say I find the new buttons quite ugly and have been really bothered by them since the change. They clash significantly with the rest of the UI and look like they were designed for touch/mobile instead of a desktop.

The classic arrows are superbly designed and, in my opinion, are the most iconic part of stack overflow.  I associate them even more strongly with the brand than I do the actual logo.  As a result, this change goes beyond a simple UI tweak for me and also impacts the part of the page I always look at first (as well as most frequently).

I strongly recommend you do not keep this new change.

Answer (score 53):

The contrast between the arrow icon and button highlight / background on voted buttons in dark mode is [too subtle](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=F48225&bcolor=92623A)

[image: dark mode vote arrow]

I have two requests...

1. Please tone this down to match the contrast ratio of the light mode version
2. Please please please test your design changes in dark mode. I feel like this just doesn't happen enough or at all. Anyone remember [this atrocity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375637/158281)?

   [image: dark mode watched tag]

---

Here's a user style that reverts this as best as I can remember the previous design looking

```css
@-moz-document regexp("https://(meta\\.)?stackoverflow.com/questions/.*") {
  .votecell .bar-pill {
    border-width: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
  
  .votecell .bar-pill.fc-black-700 {
    color: var(--black-200) !important;
  }
  
  .votecell .bar-pill .svg-icon {
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
    
  .votecell .js-vote-count {
    font-weight: 400 !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Was about to post the same thing. The contrast ratio for these buttons is [very bad](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=F48225&bcolor=92623A)... fails both WCAG AAA and WCAG AA. Pretty funny since one of the goals is "meeting WCAG compliance".

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to our attention. You are correct—reviewing the designs in dark mode doesn't happen enough. I completely agree that this (both the design solution in dark mode and lack of process in dark mode testing) is not okay. I will work immediately on a solution for the arrows in dark mode and I will also work to make sure dark mode testing is added to our process is a more formalized manner.

Comment: @Piper don't forget high-contrast mode

Comment: Well done. Hope SO restarted the A/B testing. Or now limit the results to day theme.

Answer (score 43):

([Prid's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-currently-in-a-b-testing/418890#418890), posted a few minutes after this, expresses the same sentiment but with nice diagrams showing actual before/after spacing, and with more specific reasoning for why it's distracting and feels cluttered even in light mode.  If that answer had existed already, I probably wouldn't have written this.)

---

**In dark mode, my initial impression of the new buttons is that they're too big and obnoxious looking**.  Too large a circle becomes bright on a post I've upvoted, distracting the eye from the vote total.  (See Phil's answer for a screenshot of just the buttons, but it's more apparent if you look at that big orange circle on a whole page of dark grey background with off-white text.)

**The vote total is the most interesting thing**, especially with the new **trending-sort** option that makes vote total non-monotonic as you scroll down the page, making it even more interesting to look at them.  Not at these giant buttons that are more eye-catching that the number, especially on posts I've upvoted.

Maybe this is something my brain will just get used to, I don't know; I'm not a UI expert.  I just know I disliked it enough initially to find a meta post about it where I could chime in my 2c.

**Update a couple weeks later: still feels ugly every time I click it, or look near it, especially when clicked.  Still distracting from post scores when clicked.**

If there's a significant accessibility benefit, it's something I can accept as a compromise, but hopefully something can be done.  I'm not a UI designer, don't have any specific suggestions for how it *should* look that would still achieve any accessibility goals.

The previous design is quite nice; the orange triangle for an upvote is bright but limited in area, and far enough away from the vote total.  If I had an option to keep that design, I would.

Even on posts I haven't voted on, I don't like that the new circle around the vote arrow comes a lot closer to the vote-total, distracting my eye taking it in with as quick a glance.

Comment: This, they're so out there and eye catching that I stop paying attention to the content. They make me want to click them just so they're clicked while also irritating me so much it would influence how I vote.

Comment: Well, if you are into meta-gaming, you have the option to *stop voting* for two weeks to make the A/B test fail... :')

Comment: The more perspectives shared, the better, imo ⭐

Answer (score 41):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

## No visibility of highlight in high contrast dark mode

I am in the B group with the new buttons and have been since the experiment started. I was shocked to learn that there is supposed to be highlighting on hover. Can you blame me? Here is how the buttons look:

| Screenshot | Description |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Image of the voting buttons in high contrast dark mode.] | Regular, unpressed, and not hovered |
| [image: Image of the voting buttons in high contrast dark mode. The background colour of the downvote button is almost imperceptibly different.] | With downvote hovered |
| [image: Image of the voting buttons in high contrast dark mode. The background colour of the upvote button is almost imperceptibly different.] | With upvote hovered |

If it is not very clear from the screenshots, here is an animation

[image: Animation of the voting buttons in high contrast dark mode. The mouse hovers over the downvote and the upvote button and the background changes imperceptibly.]

And if it is still not clear, the background changes from `rgb(0, 0, 0)` (black) to `rgb(0, 12, 20)` (basically still black).

I sincerely doubt this meets the WCAG compliance. Which is quite bad, considering high contrast mode whose goal is to make Stack Overflow meet or exceed WCAG AAA contrast criteria.

Comment: Also, is the cursor _behind_ the button outline? It looks like the circle outline cuts the points finger in half when you hover in the animation.

Comment: @HenryEcker I'm using inverted mouse colour, so this is normal. If the cursor is something black, the cursor is white. And if it's over something white, it's black. It's sort of "see through" so if there is white and black, it's inverting each.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 41):

There's one more button in the layout, the post score (which is [available to all users with 1k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)), and it's now nearly impossible to tap without accidentally voting:

[image: old vs new button side by side]

(Image from [Prid's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418890/6083675))

A quick measure shows that the vote buttons are 40.8px square while the score is less than 26px tall.

That's a failure for [WCAG 2.5.5: Target Size](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#target-size) which requires that controls be a minimum of 44px square. (The old buttons were better, though they probably still failed this — and indeed I had problems misclicking with them too.)

Please fix this. It affects not only mobile users but also anyone with a condition that makes it hard to precisely click.

Comment: Are you suggesting further increasing the size of the whole component by another 24.4px

Comment: @KevinB That's only one solution. It doesn't look bad to have the numbers be 32px (except it's too wide for extreme scores). The other solution would be to move the vote breakdown somewhere else (under the post? in the timeline?). Maybe there's another solution I didn't think of.

Comment: A year later... https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389965/1306850

Answer (score 26):

It's not in the middle, is it?

[image]

Maybe because you can't put an arrow with a two pixel tip into the center. The arrow needs a redesign.

Update: this seems to happen because I browse Stack Overflow at 90% zoom in Firefox. It looks better at 100% zoom, but that's too big. (And yes, Windows as the underlying OS is already set to 100%, not 125%)

Comment: On a standard Safari 100% Zoom level, the arrow *is* slightly off – the circle is 40 px to the right and 38 px to the left of the arrow's middle. It's just off enough to be [annoying](https://xkcd.com/1015/).

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. What has been seen...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi now I don't like it even more

Comment: It's a really annoying part, actually. I take notice of it every time I see the buttons.

Comment: Good thing I checked before I posted the same thing. 
I noticed this right away, and instantly hated it. It's probably a subliminal flaw that makes many people hate the new design "instinctively".
PS: With Safari on macOS with a retina display I see this https://dribbble.com/shots/21631741-Stack-Overflow-new-vote-buttons-misalignment

Comment: @GabrielR. Just goes to show how much even the simplest of feedback was "handled".

Answer (score 16):

> Wrapping the vote buttons in an outline like this makes them look more actionable, which is an environmental clue for users, especially new ones. (These are buttons, come press them!)

Except new users can't vote on questions until they have 15 reputation. It seems like if this change has any effect on new users, it will only frustrate them, because they will see the big buttons (These are buttons, come press them!), and then they will be turned away because they haven't garnered enough reputation.

Source: I have 11 reputation and it was frustrating that I couldn't downvote the redesigned buttons.

Answer (score 13):

You've added the outlines, and kept the overall width of the button relatively constant.  That preserves the overall page layout, but effectively shrinks the meaningful part of the buttons.

If my MS-paint based measurements are correct, the arrow portion of the old button had an area of 360 pixels.  The arrow portion of the new button is 100 pixels.  That's less than 1/3 the size it used to be.

A border may make it clearer that these are buttons, but replacing most of the button's label with whitespace makes it harder to tell what this button does.  I recommend making the arrow *much* larger and reducing the whitespace.

Also, the button border is too thin and light-colored (on a light themed page, at least).  I can see it fine when it's in the middle of my screen but when it's near the edge of the screen and I'm no longer at an ideal viewing angle, the round border completely washes out and becomes invisible. Even a center-screen button will wash out when there's sunlight on the screen. This makes the "small arrow" problem much more exaggerated.  High-quality monitors with wide viewing angles may not exhibit this phenomenon, but the dinky LCD panels in many laptops don't fall in that category.  Contrast and visibility looks fine in dark mode or after you've clicked an arrow and it gets a highlight. I'm only seeing this on un-clicked arrows on a light/white background.

Answer (score 10):

> Wrapping the vote buttons in an outline like this makes them look more actionable, which is an environmental clue for users, especially new ones. (These are buttons, come press them!) This should make them easier to use and more obvious, which should lead to more engagement with them.

This also makes them *loud*. (These are buttons, come press them!) As a low-activity (5k rep, 1k votes, 4 years, 680 days visited) Teams user, I find the voting buttons annoying – less so now I'm used to them, but still a little bit. (I haven't complained, because the UI differences help me to distinguish between the Team and Stack Overflow proper.) The decision on whether to vote should be made based on the answer, not based on whether the voting UI is visible and salient. While seeing the voting buttons *has* prompted me in the past, that hasn't really been a factor for me for the last two or three years. (I do still need the "questions need votes, too!" banner on occasion.) If long-time users do the majority of vote-based curation, making the voting buttons more "this is actionable!" attention-grabby might be a net UX negative.

For people who *can't* vote yet, this UI change risks diluting the "circled means actionable button" design language. This has [already frustrated a user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419166/5223757).

I expect making the voting buttons more salient and attention-grabbing to have a more significant effect on the voting of *short* answers than *long* answers. It'd be interesting to see whether your A/B testing reflects this.

If you want to improve WCAG compliance, why not just make the existing buttons black, for higher contrast? The bounding box for the existing buttons is already rectangular (and slightly bigger than the arrow); while the redesign *does* have a larger hitbox, the increased blank space means it's less visible when I blur my screen.

Comment: Just realized your last paragraph from last year pretty much summarizes my answer from today... https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389965/1306850 All about wasting time and wasting space, I guess.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if this is intended or not, but on your own posts the buttons do nothing; the mouse pointer stays the default, there is no highlight and tooltip when hovering and clicking has no effect either. This  might be confusing, especially for new users.

On Teams, where the same buttons are used, they work as normal:

[image]

and you get the 'You can't vote for your own post' error message when you click.

Comment: This is indeed confusing. Even now that they seem to have removed the tooltips. The problem is that the buttons are disabled but it's hard to tell (they don't really look disabled).

Answer (score 6):

Just an observation. I switch computers between school and home (with my same SO account). And I noticed that the A/B test is based on cookies/preferences and not on a per-account level.

Takeaway: For people that dislike the change, you can clear cookies and data for SO and there's an almost 50% chance you will fall in the other trial group (with the old buttons).

Question: Why isn't this test administered on a account level but rather on the front end?

Comment: Traditionally there are two ways to administer an experiment, one of which is on the account level and the other is based on the IP/UserAgent header combo. On the account level setup, we wouldn't be able to administer to anonymous users, even though anonymous users can't vote we can still track their vote attempt.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

On dark mode, when an answer is highlighted, the outlines around the arrows become (almost) invisible and for a second, it looks like we have tiny (arrow) buttons with a huge vertical space:

[image: Vote buttons look tiny with no outline around them]

Here's a gif:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. When we are ready to pause the experiment this week we will be analyzing results to share with the community before determining next steps on some of the bugs reported here.

Answer (score 3):

Is this test also going to do anything with the tooltip?

Comment: There aren't any changes to the tooltip as part of this experiment.

Answer (score -10):

Oh thank god this is just a test. These new orange buttons are TERRIBLE. Orange is the "something is wrong or needs your attention" color. **GREEN** is the "everything is good here" color.

Let this experiment run its course, then throw away the code, format the drive that once contained the code, then take the computers out to the parking lot and set them on fire just to be safe.

See: [Upvote UI Now an Orange Circle?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419085/upvote-ui-now-an-orange-circle?noredirect=1#comment917395_419085)

Comment: They've always been orange.

Comment: ...at least, on Stack Overflow. They _do_ have green(ish) vote buttons over on [Biking SE](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/).