# Revert to the old Upvote-Downvote buttons' design

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, user-interface

Old:
[image]

New:

[image: Upvote buttons]

This doesn't look good and doesn't match Stack Overflow's UI standard and design style. Please revert to the old design.

*Edit:*

After the revert to the old buttons, the revert back to the *new* buttons just feels so uncomfortable. My fingers feel somewhat to move the cursor to and click them. They just look so different that one can't trust these buttons—they look like they're from some other site with a *bad* design.

Comment: Do you have a reference for Stack Overflow's UI standard and design style?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, no, but my eyes say they don't blend with the rest of the UI. I don't know, but there can be one.

Comment: FWIW, there is a public reference for [Stack Overflow's design standards](https://stackoverflow.design/).

Comment: Heh, indeed, @BSMP. And look at how the upvote/downvote buttons are styled there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/970Fc.png

Comment: @CodyGray, even that's better, but it looks a bit cramped.

Comment: Stack Overflow's design is a mess of Too Much Data and Too Many Buttons and as a cherry on top Clickable Plain Text, so I don't really see why anyone would make a stink about of this one. Now we can add round buttons to the collection too.

Comment: Stack Overflow somehow manages to present too much data at once while simultaneously rendering too much blank space on the page in pursuit of "responsive design".

Comment: FYI, there's a new relevant post on MSE: [We are graduating the updated button styling for vote arrows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389359/348196)

Comment: Isn't the duplicate just a communication post and this is a feature request? Shouldn't this be reopened?

Comment: @TheMaster, I don't know why this is closed either, while this is the post about reverting it. The opposite opinion is considered a *duplicate* here, I guess.

Comment: @TheMaster this was posted when the feature was in A/B testing. The linked duplicate initially announced (later they just reused the post by editing it) the A/B testing so feedback should have gone there.

Comment: I agree that the new design is terrible, the circles just don't feel like they blend in with the otherwise "straight lines" kind of design of other elements.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I see. That makes sense.