# Why is the upvote UI now an orange circle?

Tags: discussion

Why has the upvote graphic design been changed from a green fill to this orange circle?

[image]

The green, filled arrow was 100% instantly clear. It was perfect UI/UX. The new orange coloring is a terrible decision. *Green* is the "everything is good here" color. Orange is the "something is wrong or needs your attention" color.

I've found myself hovering over the new design to figure out if I ***had*** upvoted a question or if the UI was *suggesting* I upvote it, etc.

I'd love to know the reason why this change was made and, ideally, a way to switch back to simple green.

Comment: Thank god this is just a test. Based on that thread, it looks like the buttons are universally reviled.

Comment: Don't thank god just yet. A feature being universally reviled is by no means a guarantee that it won't be implemented anyway.

Comment: I don't remember these ever being green. Always been orange as far as I can recall

Comment: @Phil - huh, you might be right. Maybe it's the *amount* of orange in the new design that caused me to think, "What's broken about my upvote?" In any case, this is a terrible change and it sounds like everybody else agrees.

Comment: the only thing that was (and still is) green is the accepted answer checkmark. I see what you mean by "amount of orange", but overall I think it fits the site's color scheme