# Tweaked message when changing an accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Occasionally I see +15 pop up for an accepted answer only to find,
when following the link to see which question it was, that the OP has swiftly
moved the acceptance to a different answer. There is nothing wrong with that per se.

I've noticed this happen when the OP is a new contributor. This made me wonder if,
motivated by generosity rather than a spontaneous change-of-heart, they were attempting a well-intentioned
acceptance of all answers out of gratitude for the collective help. New users do not
have the ability to upvote answers, so it would be understandable.

I think it is the case that when clicking a second green tick, there is nothing to
indicate to the new user that they have thereby *unticked* an existing acceptance.
The message is:

> "You accepted this answer (select to undo)"

Even though there is no hard evidence of a last-one-ticked choice, would it be worth a more explicit message? Say:

> "You have changed your accepted answer (the one most helpful to you)"

Comment: *"This made me wonder if, motivated by generosity rather than a spontaneous change-of-heart, they were attempting a well-intentioned acceptance of all answers out of gratitude for the collective help"* - it does not really pay off to speculate, that is but one of several options. The main red thread is that people misunderstand the acceptance feature. And I can assure you that this is not limited to new contributors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can see the logic behind this problem (although I don't recall it happening to me often) but I don't think your proposed solution would make a big difference. I believe that many users don't read (or even notice) the tooltip anyway.

So, if this is a real problem, a better solution would be to display a confirmation message informing the user that they've previously accepted an answer and that they're now changing the accepted answer. Basically, something like the message you get when you're about to post a *second* answer to the same question or before posting an answer to your own question.

Comment: I have little faith in people reading nag popups either, but there is only so much you can do to cope with how people have developed defences against the barrage of noise that the web throws at them daily. This is the better solution that won't really work.

Answer (score -4):

1. There is no issue in someone changing their mind about which answer should be accepted.
2. There isn't much use in reminding them that only one answer can be marked as accepted. In the case that the account is too new to upvote, that only means that they are unable to signal each useful answer accordingly, and as such there is nothing else to be done. Otherwise, the author of the post should seek to vote on answers irrespective of whether they also intend to accept one of them.
3. Other proposals inviting people to use the vote buttons are already [under testing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-currently-in-a-b-testing). And honestly, contributions towards increased, frictionless voting are the way to go. It's much more productive and useful than attempting to revamp a feature which [does not mean more than some people seem to convey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411352/outdated-answers-accepted-answer-is-now-unpinned-on-stack-overflow).

There is hardly a problem solved in this proposal. The way I see it, this was brought up because the change of accepted answer brought noise to the answerer who had their answer accepted temporarily due to the reputation changes. Maybe there is just too much reward in having an answer accepted in the first place, and none of this would have been brought up if the accepted answer had no effect on reputation.