# Could Stack Overflow for Teams set the page favicon?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, favicon

If you're [updating button styling on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418851/5223757), the only significant UI differences between Stack Overflow proper and Teams will be:

- the colour of the top bar (very subtle in Dark Mode);
- the icon in the sidebar (not visible if the sidebar is disabled);
- the icon at the start of the question (not visible if scrolled down);
- the "people asked" section (not visible if scrolled up / down);
- the URL (hidden by some browsers);
- the end of the page title (hidden if the question title is long).

I'm used to using favicons to tell the difference between Stack Exchange sites (on the browsers that still show them), but that doesn't work for *Stack Overflow for Teams*. Even though the Team has its own icon, that icon is not set as the page's favicon.

That means I've been using the vote button style as the main visual indicator for which site I'm on; unless answers are *really* long, it's visible no matter the scroll position (except underneath questions, where the "people asked" section is visible). If this indicator goes away, I'd have to scroll to the top of the page, or look at the greyed-out text in the URL bar. It would be a lot easier if I could just look at the favicon, same as for every other Stack Exchange site.

There's a potential issue if companies put their corporate logo as their Teams logo: they might not be able to tell their Teams pages apart from other sites with the same image. However, Stack Overflow for Teams users are probably also Stack Overflow users; this change would at least give them the option to make the distinction how they wanted.

Comment: A bit tangential to the discussion: "*That means I've been using [...]*" I'd assume the left sidebar navigation menu is hidden for some reason? Because it also shows the Teams name and logo on there.

Comment: @AndrewT. It's hidden when the relevant option in the profile is set, and when the viewport is narrow.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I just noticed it in the list. It's just the different left sidebar (or collapsed if disabled/narrow window) navigation menu is the most obvious thing IMHO.