# Results of the vote arrows styling experiment

Tags: discussion, voting, user-interface, a-b-testing

**TL;DR: Overall, the experiment was a success with a positive lift in overall votes in the variant group, however, we will not be graduating the experiment.**

In June, we [conducted an experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-a-b-testing-has-concluded) to test updating the styling of the voting buttons for both questions and answers to improve accessibility and meet [WCAG compliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Content_Accessibility_Guidelines). The experiment lasted approx. 2.5 weeks (launched June 23, concluded July 12). In this post, we’ll go over how the experiment performed and outline next steps.

### Experiment results

The goal of the experiment was to measure and understand how the updated vote buttons performed, as they were made to look more actionable. The primary metric was the number of votes between the experiment groups, up or down. This gave us an indication as to whether or not the updated vote buttons influenced engagement with posts on the site.

We bucketed the voting events into all votes (voting either up or down), and by downvotes and upvotes only. Our null hypothesis for each bucket was that the baseline (also referred to as control) and new experiment groups voted on posts at the same rate (Voting Engagement).

Here’s what we found. Please note that the raw event values were omitted. For reference, the baseline group did not receive the treatment. The variant group is where we updated the voting buttons.

| Vote Type | Experiment Group | Voting Engagement | Percent Change | Confidence Interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All Votes | Baseline | 1.15% |  | [1.11%-1.20%] |
| All Votes | Variant | 1.47% | +27.8% | [1.42%-1.52%] |
| Downvotes Only | Baseline | 0.09% |  | [0.07%-0.10%] |
| Downvotes Only | Variant | 0.17% | +88.9% | [0.16%-0.19%] |
| Upvotes Only | Baseline | 1.07% |  | [1.03%-1.11%] |
| Upvotes Only | Variant | 1.29% | +20.6% | [1.25%-1.34%] |

We were able to reject the null hypothesis (p<0.001) that these experiment groups were the same for every vote type bucket. The updated vote buttons outperformed the baseline for all three buckets, albeit we’re discussing a very small conversion rate in the context of visits. In this context, conversion rate is whether or not a given registered user visiting a question logged a voting event.

You’ll also notice that the conversion rate for downvotes is a very small proportion of all votes by the conversion rate alone. This is fairly typical, though. Downvotes can range between 10-15 percent of voting actions in a given month.

Additionally, [Larnu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-a-b-testing-has-concluded#comment915931_418853) was interested in monitoring if there was a difference in answer accept rates.  We monitored this between the experiment groups and here’s what we found. Despite not making any visual changes to the accept answer button, we saw a positive lift in the variant group.

| Experiment Group | Answers Accepted | % Change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Baseline | 14,949 |  |
| Variant | 15,499 | +3.7% |

### Conclusion and next steps

These results suggest that we should proceed with the new style buttons going forward. A 27.8 percent lift in voting engagement among users should translate into better questions and answers getting surfaced, especially over a longer period of time. However, despite the positive lift in overall votes in the experiment group, we’ve decided not to graduate this experiment for a few reasons.

First, we want to take a more holistic approach with any question page changes we make to improve accessibility. This means looking at the question page as a whole and determining other areas where we might be falling short with accessibility. We realized for this experiment that there wasn’t enough lead time to solicit and incorporate design feedback from Meta. Before we launch any future experiments, we will communicate early and iterate on designs. Additionally, there were accessibility issues that Meta raised in the [experiment announcement post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-a-b-testing-has-concluded) that need to be addressed and re-tested across site themes and in high contrast mode.

For these reasons, we think it’s best to roll this into another experiment as part of a broader initiative in the future as there is still work to be done. Thank you for sharing feedback in the previous post. We will review them and determine where we can make improvements to the design as we continue to improve accessibility on the platform.

Comment: I don't think I'll ever comprehend your statistical decisions. A [2% improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418491/6296561) is statistically significant, but a whopping **80%** increase in downvotes and 27% overall isn't good enough to meet the cut. P values aside, how is this increase _not_ good enough to keep the feature?

Comment: Full disclosure, I'm not even a fan of that button design, but if the change had this much of an effect on engagement, sign me up. We also receive a ton of comments about votes. Even though this wouldn't make as much of a dent as an absolute increase of double digits (read: getting vote engagement above 10%), it's still a contribution. Is this yet another case of "doesn't fix everything so it's bad"? More downvotes is also incredibly important; it's a core site moderation feature, and historically, not nearly enough downvotes have been cast. An 80% increase is an incredible improvement

Comment: i mean, results are results, but i'm more curious in the why, and what groups in particular, increased their engagement with voting button just because they were made visually smaller and given a border. Running with results without understanding the *why* bit is what's concerned me with past changes. Were people literally not seeing voting buttons? or did the shape of the buttons changing remind people that they exist or cause some form of... curiosity-based usage.

Comment: In that same vein, I could see the possibility of people clicking the downvote button to see if the "Why are you downvoting?" dialog from collectives came along with it.

Comment: @Zoe Did you read the final two paragraphs? The results aren't the reason for holding this back; wanting to solicit feedback from Meta and respecting the design & accessibility concerns _we raised_ is the given reasoning. I don't think we should bemoan staff for explicitly listening to Meta feedback.

Comment: @zcoop98 I did, and it still screams of "we're not implementing this now so we maybe can do a little more at some undetermined point in the future, because this doesn't fix everything", then flash forward 1-2 years in an optimistic scenario before it's revisited, while the problems still exist in the meanwhile. The thing works; it could be better, but that should be done in an iteration 2 while iteration 1 is live, rather than throwing iteration 1 under the bus for not doing enough. It's this mentality that causes accessibility to remain bad in all places of importance

Comment: Hum, that was the "Orange = DANGER...!!" Arrow Experiment... Fouff..., glad it didn't last long, ... and won't be adopted...! (Got my Upvote this time...)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine We're also very excited about these results! We want to take this learning forward but want to do so in concert with other improvements and the feedback we got from Meta on the test. We're looking to make more holistic changes so it doesn't feel like a development Jenga tower.

Comment: Are there at least plans to do it soon?

Comment: I don't know. This is weird for a web company, but it sounds like they are preferring a waterfall methodology to an agile one.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Given how much flak SE takes when they make changes, I can understand them being leery of making incremental changes. OTOH, a major portion of the reason they take a lot of flak for making changes is that they are not all that responsive to making changes/adjustments when the feedback is that the changes are poor/harmful. [Note: *Sometimes* SE is responsive to feedback, but those times are overwhelmed in people's perception by the times when SE is actively not responsive to feedback that a change is poor/harmful.]

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine thanks for sharing your feedback. In addition to the reasons stated in the last paragraph for not graduating the experiment we think it would be beneficial to take a step back and prioritize the next initiative (hasn't been prioritized yet for this quarter but conversations are happening). As soon as we have a decision, the next steps are to communicate to Meta about the initiative in more detail (what we want to do, why we're doing it and some experiments we plan on conducting). Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @KevinB from what I could tell, there wasn't any additional information in our A/B testing tool about what groups were voting other than they were registered users. Were you interested in viewing which specific user types (e.g. mods vs registered) were voting?

Comment: The new vote buttons looked super bloated-balloon like and reminded me of those really cheap forums that you would come across when you go to the 10th page on Google search results. Could you use some other design that'd make it button-like but not as obtrusive?

Comment: I'm very skeptical of drawing conclusions from a 2.5 week experiment on this topic. That feels like a very short period of time. I think with such a short window you might see more engagement simply because users are noticing something **different**, not necessarily something **better** on their screen.

Comment: Why is this now on?

Comment: @tanj92 Did this experiment measure *votes*, as in, the final outcome of interacting with the page? Or did it measure *clicks*, where clicking a button after having previously voted undoes it, and then perhaps clicking a third time to reinstate the vote? Lots of people have been reporting issues with it not being clear whether the button was pressed or not like https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389668/i-cant-see-if-ive-already-voted-on-something which might lead to people clicking more than once to "check" or thinking it needs to be pressed again.

Comment: It would really be cool if we could do the same experiment again now in a symmetric but reversed setting. But I guess chances are very slim for that unfortunately. Anyway if in a repetition of the experiment this time the old styles would perform better we would know that the 2.5 weeks of experiment duration are too small and the results are heavily biased. If the results are not reversed but just different, we would still know that there is a problem with the conclusion. Only if the same results are obtained within error limits one would trust the results of similar experiments in the future.

Answer (score 18):

**TLDR You actually graduated the experiment but upon graduation no positive lift on voting could be found anymore. It's puzzling. Something must be wrong. Are you sure that simple changes can lead to such strong effects?**

After the style changes went live on the network at the end of May 2023, one could study the effects on the real scale but of course without A/B testing. [Plotting the voting activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390219/260073) shortly before and after the style update doesn't show any increase in voting at all.

In strong contrast are these results here especially given the relatively small confidence intervals. Even if I take the most unfortunate borders of the confidence intervals I should see at least 10% increase in voting which however, now that the style change is active, doesn't seem to materialize.

I think it's puzzling. I have no reason to not trust any of the analyses, neither this one nor the recent one, but it's disturbing that the promised increase in voting activity doesn't seem to be present when the feature is finally live. What can the reason be for that? The results were used to argue for the introduction of the feature against the opinion of the meta community. Therefore, the numbers were important.

Anyway I found 20% increase in up-voting and a whooping 90% increase in down-voting always kind of hard to believe for such a small change. Much too good to be true. Of course that is not a proof to the contrary.