# Selected voting buttons on meta could use more contrast

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

I noticed that as of today, the design change to the +/- buttons which I recall seeing discussed a while ago has been implemented.

The circles around the up and down arrows *does* (in my opinion) make it more clear that they're clickable buttons, and that's great!  BUT, once you actually press one of the buttons, why is the change so barely perceptible?  Here is an example from another Meta question I recently upvoted:

[image]

If you know what to look for, it's clear enough:  the background of the selected one is shaded and the outline is black instead of gray.  But, the differences in this version are much more subtle than that between the light gray (unselected) triangle and the black (selected) triangle in the old system.

I could definitely see someone clicking on a question they'd previously liked and then forgotten about, not looking too closely at the new voting button graphics, pressing the up arrow again, and so accidentally *undoing* their +1.  Paying attention would prevent this problem, but certainly the intent behind the design change wasn't to make the users' choices **less** visible to themselves?

Would it be possible to have the actual arrow/triangle's color still change, but also keep the circle?

By the way, the orange-highlighted triangle-in-circle graphic on the main site is MUCH clearer, but I know that wouldn't fit with Meta's grayscale theme.

[image]

Comment: Related on MSE: [It’s hard to tell how I’ve voted on meta sites. Please make selected and unselected vote buttons different colors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389563/it-s-hard-to-tell-how-i-ve-voted-on-meta-sites-please-make-selected-and-unselec)

Comment: @toolic LOL! I thought it was odd that no one else had posted about it yet...

Comment: I wouldn't close this question. Because having a cross site duplicate here on SO meta, will prove to be useful to have as a duplicate target. I expect you're not the only person that feels this way, which means there are more questions that ask essentially the same thing.

Comment: Maybe they could add a drop-shadow on the buttons for a 3D effect? (Yes, I know you can't downvote comments any more ;)

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention. This is not by design - we'll work on a solution in the near future and update the post here once we've addressed it.

Comment: @Catija did you somehow forget that this was all brought up last October?

Comment: @Phil I appreciate that the information was brought up last year and I apologise that it wasn't addressed for this rollout. We went to a lot of effort to document the concerns from the test so that we could keep them in mind when making this change live. It seems to have been overlooked. Apologies.

Comment: @Catija _"We went to a lot of effort to document the concerns"_... [so did we](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418851/283366), the community but I guess ignoring feedback is the norm now. Glad I documented my user styles from the experiment

Comment: The new change looks so bad to me. they should've put style option so we could fall back to the previous style.

Comment: @AndrewMorton https://i.stack.imgur.com/a940P.png :-)

Comment: Additional circles around the arrow make it look too cluttered for my taste. Others may like it, but it just looks like a Hodge-podge of shapes, e.g. "Square peg in a round hole".. (actually triangle here...)

Comment: Upvoted just to see the new change for myself

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Posting [the same answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389773/1324540) I put on the MSE version of this question.

I want to acknowledge everyone who has indicated that with the new buttons it is harder to tell whether you have already voted on something or not. This is an issue that makes it harder to engage on the platform, which we take seriously. We saw that this problem was especially prevalent on the Meta sites because they use grayscale.

We just rolled out a change across Meta sites on the network, making it much more obvious to see that you have voted on a question or answer. Now, after you have voted the whole button should appear dark, rather than just the outer ring, with the arrow inside appearing lighter.

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

If you find a Meta site where the updated style is not live, please let us know so we can address it.

On the network sites (excluding Meta) the coloration of the voting buttons varies based on the theme of the site, so they don’t look the same everywhere. If there are specific sites where you are finding the same problem of visibility after voting, please let us know in the comments here.

Comment: I experience the same problem on "German Language", the core site, not just meta; maybe because I'm mildly colorblind. I don't experience a difference in it being grayscale or not. Please improve the contrast!

Comment: @userunknown thanks for flagging this, we are keeping track of the sites where users report this to be an issue