# What's the limit to how many emojis a post can have?

Tags: discussion, formatting

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58542757/%ef%b8%8f-selenium-scroll-navigate-next-page-scrolling-to-top-navigate) has "a lot" of emojis. It's clear that the user is trying to get attention with them.

> Thanks for the interaction! I'm really hoping to get this solved.

What are the *rules* regarding emojis?
Should post bodies (or question titles) have emojis?
Are they frowned upon?

*They were recently edited out of the question, but [here is how they used to look like](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58542757/2)*

Comment: It's 11. Or the poster's reputation divided by 1000, rounded up. Whatever is greater.

Comment: If it's unnecessary or fluff, get rid of it. ‍♂️ doesn't help anyone understand the question.

Comment: My rules of thumb is one if it's not simply design choice for the question. A question about testing allowed emojis may have all of them in every possible order and I will be fine with it.

Comment: As for everything else on the site: does it help the content? No? then it should be removed

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381660/6296561 Also, there aren't gonna be system-level blocks because they have legitimate uses, but if you notice useless uses like that, remove it.

Comment: The limit is identical to the limit of any other character a question can have. You can ask an all-emoji question if you want to

Comment: I reopened this because both targets were specifically about titles, and this is about the question body itself.

Answer (score 20):

The limit is *zero* if they're not useful, as in this case.

Unless the emojis play a fundamental role in the question (see below), they're completely unnecessary and should be removed as soon as possible.

It is appropriate if a question includes emojis because it asks about them.

If emojis are present in code blocks but the emojis themselves or their behavior are not being asked about (such as emojis in code comments), you should remove them. Otherwise, leave them be.

In general, if they don't add any value to the question, remove them.

Example of bad use of emojis in titles:

> ‍♂️ Selenium - Scroll --> navigate next page (scrolling to top) --> navigate back check scroll position

Example of good use of emojis in titles:

> Why does printing the emoji "Man shrugging" (‍♂️) cause a "Male" emoji (♂️) to be displayed?

Comment: Oooh. I can answer your second sample question: ‍♂️